# How can one find undocumented options or option values in Mathematica?

Tags: options, undocumented

*Mathematica* has a lot of undocumented or poorly documented options.

1. How does one go about working out if there is an undocumented option that might solve a particular problem?
2. How does one work out what the universe of possible values the option might take are? (This also applies to options whose existence is documented, but where the range of valid values isn't.)

---

As background, here is a collection of ones I and others have found so far:

**Graphics**

The `Method` option is an option for `Graphics` and related commands like `BarChart`. It is mentioned in the notes in the documentation and turns up in `Options[Graphics]` but is not listed as an option in the documentation with any examples. There are many sub-options, none of which are explicitly documented.

- `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}` removes whitespace that *Mathematica* adds as a tiny rim to each plot. (pointed out by Sjoerd)
- `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}` does what it says (see Brett Champion's [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177471/gridline-on-top-of-a-bar-chart-in-mathematica) and [this MathGroup thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/11783ce8923d76b4)). `Dynamic` `GridLines` using this option are present in much of the graphical Wolfram|Alpha output (See, e.g. the edited [number line code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797651/plotting-a-number-line-in-mathematica/6806152#6806152)).
- `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> True}` also does what it says. (see [TomD's comment on Brett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177471/gridline-on-top-of-a-bar-chart-in-mathematica#comment-8617209))
- `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> angle}}` sets the angle that decides when two points in a plot are not further subdivided - default is `5\[Degree]`. (see Yaro's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572183/strange-sinx-graph-in-mathematic/4572266#4572266) and the [relevant page in Stan Wagon's book](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=EbVrWLNiub4C&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&d#v=onepage&q&f=false). Also, a `Plot` [version comparison by Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204383/how-plot-works-in-mathematica/7243229#7243229))
- The option `"MessagesHead"` is used to track the origin of calls to `Plot`, etc., made by dependent plot functions such as `LogPlot`, `LogLinearPlot`, and `DateListLogPlot`.  This allows the correct options and messages to be passed to and from the general function. An example of its use can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399216/how-to-change-the-default-colordata-used-in-mathematicas-plot/5651064#5651064).
- `ImageSizeRaw` option for various plotting and graphics functions is not documented, but [turns out to be important for embedding CDFs into web pages](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html).
- `PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}`, as [documented here](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/mathematica/14131/Wacky-Font-Substitution-in-eps-Export), stops minus signs, parentheses and the like from being in *Mathematica*'s special fonts rather than the selected text font.
- [s0rce discovered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5718/8) that the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option works for line plots (`ListPlot`, `Plot`, etc). Possible values include `"Reverse"`, `"Log"` `"Log10"` – the last of these being itself undocumented.
- Not strictly a graphics function, but often used to create nice-looking ticks, `FindDivisions` has an undocumented `Method` option: for example, `FindDivisions[{-1.8,8.9}, 6, Method -> "ExtendRange"]` gives the encompassing divisions `{-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}`, as does `Method -> Automatic`; any other setting for `Method` gives the *inner* divisions: `{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}`.
- You can control the amount a `PieChart` segment pops out of the chart when you click it using `SetOptions[Charting'iSectorChart, {PopoutSpacing -> n}]`, where `n` is numeric. The default is 0.2; for fun, try a negative number. You can suppress this behaviour altogether using `SetOptions[Charting'SectorChart, {Popout -> False}]` (in both these examples, change the quote mark to a backquote).
- For some `Plot` functions the setting for the `PlotStyle` option can be specified as a function as well as a list of graphics directives. The earliest reference for this undocumented feature is [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8225/125). Additional examples of this `PlotStyle` usage for `Plot` and `ParametricPlot` are: [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8644/125), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14607/125), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77309/125), and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48879/125).

**Panels**

As noted in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894237/what-do-these-undocumented-style-options-in-mathematica-do), these options pop up in some graphics/panels, but are unrecognised when one uses them explicitly in `Panel`, `Graphics` or related structures:

- `LineColor`
- `FrontFaceColor`
- `BackFaceColor`
- `GraphicsColor`

**Legends**

There seem to be a lot of undocumented options here:

- `AssembleLegendContainer`
- `BubbleScaleLegend`
- `ColorGradientLegend`
- `ContourLegend`
- `CurveLegend`
- `GridLegend`
- `Legend`
- `LegendContainer`: `` SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend,  Legending`LegendContainer -> Identity] `` removes the border from legends (thanks to Mr.Wizard)
- `LegendHeading`
- `LegendImage`
- `LegendItemLayout`
- `LegendLayout`
- `LegendPane`
- `LegendPosition`
- `LegendReap`
- `Legends`
- `LegendSize`
- `LegendSow`

**Equation-solving and minimisation/optimisation**

- `Evaluated -> False` option of `FindRoot` (TomD in comments)

**System options for evaluation**

Per acl's answer below, `SystemOptions[]` reveals many hidden options using the following syntax. These can be set using `SetSystemOptions[]`.

- `"PackedArrayOptions" /. SystemOptions[]`
- `"CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions[]`

Although this book by Nancy Blachman
has been written for Version 2, it is still not a bad starting point:
[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematica-Quick-Reference-Version-Spiral/dp/0201628805](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201628805)

Comment: One that perhaps deserves mention is the `Evaluated-> False` option of `FindRoot`, known to me from a MathGroup discussion by Andrzej Kozlowski & [szhorvat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/695132/szabolcs).  See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_frm/thread/21e4e427b0eff534/9ce4c9359cb2819d%20#9%20ce4c9359cb2819d).  They consider the example `FindRoot[NIntegrate[Exp[a x], {x, 0, 1}] == 2, {a, 1}, Evaluated ->
False]`

Comment: I see that I lost the Accept.  I think that Simon Woods' method is valuable, but how would you use it to find something like ``Legending`LegendContainer`` or ["MessagesHead"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4716/121)?  I argue that `Trace` is still more powerful and applicable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard both would be fine answers but I thought Simon's was more straightforward for bulk investigation, and I can't mark multiple answers as accepted. Don't worry there will be some goodies along later.

Comment: @Verbeia I have asked Brett Chamption and received information that there is also "FrameInFront" option. [comments to this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32231/5478). Not that useful as `AxesInFront` but you may want to add this to that list :)

Comment: ScalingFunctions seem to stop working with ListPlot.

Comment: @JánosTóth can you elaborate on why the book you linked would be helpful in this case (to help decide on whether to get it or not)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

One thing you can do is look for options which appear in a function's `Options` but do not have a `::usage` message. Of course, some of the results actually *are* documented in the help, they just don't have a usage message. Here's a function to do it:

```
undoc[x_Symbol]:=Select[Options[x],!StringQ@MessageName[Evaluate@First@#,"usage"]&];
undoc[_] = {};

(* e.g. *)
undoc[Plot]
Out[3]= {Evaluated->Automatic,ImageSizeRaw->Automatic}
```

The following runs this function on all symbols in `System` context, and presents the results in a grid. Some functions (like `Cell`) have huge lists of options with no usage message, these ones I skip over (just printing out the function name) to save space.

```
Grid[Select[{#,undoc[Symbol[#]]}&/@Names["System`*"],
Last@#=!={}&&(Length@Last@#<10||Print@First@#)&],Frame->All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 40):

#### 1. Discovery may be aided by `Trace` and related tools.

- I recommend [WReach's traceView functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/5527117#5527117).

#### 2. Simple observation and experimentation.  Simple does not imply easy.

---

As an example, to find the answer to ["Can the frame border on a BarChart Legend be removed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074209), I used:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"}] // Trace // InputForm
```

`InputForm` was used so that details of `Graphics` objects could be viewed and searched as text.

In the long output that was produced, I first searched to see when `Framed` appeared, and then I began working backward to see what precipitated it.  After some digging, backtracking, and a few dead ends I came across:

```
{Legending`LegendDump`container, Legending`LegendDump`position, 
  Legending`LegendDump`layout, Legending`LegendDump`appearance} = 
 OptionValue[
  Legending`GridLegend, {LegendAppearance -> Automatic, 
   Legending`LegendPosition -> 
    Automatic}, {Legending`LegendContainer, Legending`LegendPosition, 
   Legending`LegendLayout, LegendAppearance}]
```

I had observed or guessed, from my digging, that `` Legending`LegendDump`container `` related to the `Framed` component, and here was (one place) where its value was set.  Experimentation proved that this option affected the desired object, at least in some cases:

```
SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend, Legending`LegendContainer -> "Nonsense"]

BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}, ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"}]
```

Seeing how this behaved, it was obvious to try `Identity`.  Testing with several bar charts suggested that it was at least somewhat durable, therefore I posted it as an answer.

Comment: This is an interesting trick; can you give a short example of how one can find an undocumented option using `Trace`? I have found the ones I use either by being told by others or by looking at things like `SystemOptions`.

Comment: In the edited version of the question, these responses relate to points (1) and (2). Sorry about that.

Comment: That is a useful observation. I had never noticed this kind of thing in the mass of `Trace` output.

Answer (score 25):

I find `SetSystemOptions["PackedArrayOptions" -> {"UnpackMessage" -> True}]` to be useful: it emits a message when a packed array is unpacked. This may happen automatically, sometimes slowing down things greatly. This is useful in situations like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853787/take-some-data-return-a-pure-piecewise-function/6891751#6891751) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405304/memory-use-of-apply-vs-map-virtual-memory-use-and-lock-ups/6405491#6405491). One way one would find out that such an option exists is `"PackedArrayOptions" /. SystemOptions[]`.

In fact, `SetSystemOptions[]` shows up a number of interesting and undocumented options. For instance, `"CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions[]` gives a set of options for when things get compiled, whether or not to generate reports when something can't be compiled or parts of it call external definitions, whether to inline compiled functions called from within a compiled function, etc.

Answer (score 23):

John Fultz [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353658/421225) which had an undocumented option.

```
CellPrint[{
  Cell["Click to open the section", "Section", 
       System`WholeCellGroupOpener -> True],
  TextCell["Some text"]}]
```

This produces a section cell that if you click anywhere on it will open and close the whole section.

Comment: This is interesting, but I think you got the wrong question.  Shouldn't it be here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461814/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Maybe, maybe not... This question is about undocumented *options* (it has been rephrased to make it into a question that wouldn't be closed - see the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7087149/revisions)), my question was about undocumented *functions*. Maybe we should revert the title to make it once again into one of the dreaded [Big List](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/156389) questions.

Comment: This question is *how to find* undocumented options.  Unless your answer can be distilled to "look for posts by John Fultz" then I do not believe it is valid.  I would rather you edit the other post title to "undocumented Mathematica functionality" and post this there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I know what the question currently says - I was answering its original phrasing and intent. I wrote my question to complement this one - assuming that Verbia still had her original intent. I'm happy to move this answer and modify my question if other people think that is appropriate.

Answer (score 16):

### NIntegrate Method options

There are many `Method` settings to use in `NIntegrate` and many but not all of their suboptions are documented the [tutorial on `NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html).  Some of these may be found by

```
?NIntegrate`StrategiesDump`*Options
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Others may be found by

```
?NIntegrate`StrategiesDump`*Properties
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note in the case shown, the options are the same as the `Method` options of [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) and

```
SystemOptions["PiecewiseOptions"]

(* {"PiecewiseOptions" -> {"BooleanResult" -> Automatic, 
     "ConditionSimplifier" -> Automatic, 
     "DirectExpansionCrossovers" -> {10, 7., False}, 
     "EliminateConditions" -> True, "ExpandSpecialPiecewise" -> True, 
     "FactorInequalities" -> True, "FullStrengthInference" -> False, 
     "OrderlessConditions" -> Automatic, "Parallel" -> Automatic, 
     "RefineConditions" -> True, "Simplification" -> True, 
     "StrictCalculus" -> Automatic, "ValueSimplifier" -> Automatic}} *)
```

Note also that giving a wrong option to `NIntegrate` methods yields the list of properties as an error message:

```
NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"InterpolationPointsSubdivision", "Foo" -> True}]
```

> `NIntegrate::moptxn`: The option `Foo` of the method `InterpolationPointsSubdivision` is not one of `{MaxSubregions, Method, SymbolicProcessing}`. >>

Answer (score 6):

Possibly the following file contains more options, though admittedly I have not spent much time looking for them. This is the file that contains the information used by `SyntaxInformation`

```
ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Kernel", 
      "TextResources", $Language}, "FunctionInformation.m"]
```

This file contains a lot of options, both "Symbol options" and "string options". Not all "kinds of options" are listed here, at least the "option" `"OptionNames"` of `SyntaxInformation` is not present here. The file also does not appear to contain nested options.