# How do you convert a string containing a number in C scientific notation to a Mathematica number?

Tags: import, string-manipulation

Suppose I have a string containing the C-representation of a floating point number; for example

```
s = "1.23e-5"
```

and I want to convert this to a *Mathematica* number.  How can I do this?

`ToExpression[s]` gives `` Plus[-5, Times[1.23`, e]] ``.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is `ImportString["1.23e-5", "Table"][[1, 1]]` which seems like rather a large hack!

Comment: Amazing that the language doesn't include a simple straightforward function to do this!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I think probably the cleanest way to do this (at least, if you have only a single string, or are faced with a separate string for each number you wish to convert as a result of some other process) is to use the undocumented function `` Internal`StringToDouble ``, i.e.:

```
s = "1.23e-5";
Internal`StringToDouble[s]
```

which gives:

```
0.0000123
```

However, if you are trying to convert many such numbers at once, the standard, documented methods (`Import`, `Read`, etc.), are likely to represent better approaches.

UPDATE:  As of at least [version 12.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246449/is-internalstringtodouble-broken-in-12-3) the proper way to invoke this is:

```
Internal`StringToMReal["1.23e-5"]
```

Comment: Another one from Mr.Undocumented!

Comment: Always try to avoid `ToExpression`!

Comment: This seems like functionality that should be available (officially) in Mathematica.  Will Wolfram accept feature-requests?

Comment: @FJRA Why should `ToExpression` be avoided?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe because it might lead you to a code leak. What if there is dangerous code within the string? Or something innocent like a equal sign (=) may set any of your variables.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Internal\`StringToDouble[]` can produce unexpected results: `"-1"` is parsed as -1.0 but `" -1"` (extra leading space) is parsed as 1.0 (sign dropped). Also "1.0000000000000000" is parsed as 1. but if you add one more zero it returns `$Failed["Bignum"]` and no message is generated.

Answer (score 22):

```
s = "1.23e-5"

# &[Read[#, Number], Close@#]&[ StringToStream@s ]
```

Which is not as good as what you started with.  Note that [it is important to close the stream](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion).

---

Szabolcs says this is difficult to read.  That was surely not my intention.  You could also write it verbosely like this:

```
fromC =
    Module[{output, stream},
      stream = StringToStream[#];
      output = Read[stream, Number];
      Close[stream];
      output
    ] &;

fromC[s]
```

Comment: Making the `Close` in the second argument of a function that never uses it is a nice trick. I did some benchmarking and found the more readable version to be about 55% slower. An alternative way of writing it as a composition of functions is `fromC = StringToStream /* {Read[#, Number] &, Close} /* Through /* First` which is just about 10% slower. In any case it doesn't matter because `Internal\`StringToDouble` is much faster than any of these.

Answer (score 17):

On version 7 `` Internal`StringToDouble `` fails on long strings, and fails to recognize exponents:

```
Internal`StringToDouble["3.1415926535897932385"]

Internal`StringToDouble /@ {"3.14159", "3.14159e-02", "3.14159e+02"}
```

> ```
> $Failed["Bignum"]
>
> {3.14159, 3.14159, 3.14159}
> ```

This sent me looking for another way to convert numeric strings.  [Using `Trace`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/810/121) on `ImportString` I found another internal function that does what I need: `` System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable ``.

Being an internal function is it not error tolerant and if fed bad arguments it will crash the kernel.  The syntax is as follows:

```
System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable[
  table,
  {{pre, post}, {neg, pos}, dot},
  False
]
```

```
table  :   table of strings, depth = 2; need not be rectangular.  
pre    :   List of literal strings to ignore if preceding the digits (only first match tried).  
post   :   List of literal strings to ignore if following the digits (only first match tried).  
neg    :   literal string to interpret a negative sign (`-`).  
pos    :   literal string to interpret a positive sign (`+`).  
dot    :   literal string to interpret as decimal point.
```

(Using `True` in place of `False` causes a call to `` System`Convert`TableDump`TryDate `` that I do not yet understand.)

Example:

```
System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable[
  {{"-£1,234.141592653589793e+007"}, {"0.97¢", "140e2kg"}},
  {{{"£"}, {"kg", "¢"}}, {"-", "+"}, "."},
  False
]
```

> {{-1.2341415926535898*^10}, {0.97, 14000.}}

Comment: Ah, kernel spelunking, +1.

Comment: Nice work! I'm sure this function will be useful. Regarding ``Internal`StringToDouble`` on 7: exponents are recognised if you first use `StringReplace[nums, "e"|"E" -> "*^"]`.

Comment: @Oleksandr thanks, and good to know about `StringToDouble`!

Comment: `ParseTable` is great. Very fast and handles integers as well as reals. I've used it a bunch of times when I know my input is clean, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ssch Glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 16):

Another solution would be to use `SemanticImportString` (new in 10).

Borrowing some code from Mr.Wizard so that I can compare my solution to his:

```
strings =
  ToString @ Row[RandomChoice /@ {{"-", ""}, {#}, {"e"}, {"-", ""}, Range@12}] & /@ 
    RandomReal[{0, 10}, 15000];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Internal`StringToDouble /@ strings // AccurateTiming

System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable[
  {strings}, {{{}, {}}, {"-", "+"}, "."}, False
] // AccurateTiming

Interpreter["Number"][strings]   // AccurateTiming

SemanticImportString[
     StringJoin[Riffle[strings, ";"]],
     {"Number"}, 
     "List",
     Delimiters -> ";"
] // AccurateTiming
```

> 0.00671892
>
> 0.00504799
>
> 12.980645
>
> 0.0426966

Now as you can see there is still an order of magnitude, but at least `SemanticImport` is strict with things that are not numbers, while `` Internal`StringToDouble["foo"] `` returns `0.`.

Some of the types in `Interpreter` will benefit from using `SemanticImport` internally when called on lists of strings in the future.

As far as the current speed of `Interpreter` there is only so much you can gain if you want to support things like

```
Interpreter[
    Restricted["Number", {0, 10, 0.5}],
    NumberPoint -> "baz",
    NumberSigns -> {"foo", "bar"}
]["bar5baz5"]
```

> 5.5

Comment: Thank you Carlo, this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 15):

`First[ImportString["1.23e-5", "List"]]` might be slightly less hack-y than your suggestion in the comments...

Comment: What about a string like "2.12e"? You can see in MMA examples where such strings are generated as CForm/FortranForm `ScientificForm[2.12, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", #3}] &)]`

Comment: @Plato is that a standard form?  It looks like an error.

Comment: @Plato: That's funny; I don't think I've ever seen a superfluous `e` being added to numbers between $1$ and $10$, I must say. Neither `CForm[]` nor `FortranForm[]` do this, and `ScientificForm[]` will only do that if you mess with options like you have.

Comment: @J.M. You are right! It does not generate numbers that ends with such a "e" as I wrote. Actually I got misled by the documentation of `ScientificForm`. You can also check there the `NumberFormat ` example in the Options section of the documentation for `ScientificForm`. There they show how to produce Fortran-like forms. Test with a number like "2.12" and see the foolish "e" appears. But it is indeed not a general truth about the `CForm`or `FortranForm`.

Comment: @Plato: Okay, but I think that's a rather contrived example. I don't think I've seen an entity like `2.12e` in applications...

Answer (score 11):

Version 10 introduced [`Interpreter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpreter.html) which would seem suited to this task:

> `Interpreter[form]`
>   represents an interpreter object that can be applied to a string to try to interpret it as an object of the specified form.

```
Interpreter["Number"]["1.23e-5"]
```

> ```
> 0.0000123
> ```

Unfortunately it seems that like many new-in-10 functions this is far from optimized.  In fact I would say its performance is nothing short of abysmal for this particular task.

Some string data to test with:

```
strings =
  ToString @ Row[RandomChoice /@ {{"-", ""}, {#}, {"e"}, {"-", ""}, Range@12}] & /@ 
    RandomReal[{0, 10}, 15000];
```

Timings for `Interpreter` against `StringToDouble` and `ParseTable` (see the other answers):

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Internal`StringToDouble /@ strings // AccurateTiming

System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable[
  {strings}, {{{}, {}}, {"-", "+"}, "."}, False
] // AccurateTiming

Interpreter["Number"] /@ strings   // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.0052075
>
> 0.00645107
>
> 10.625608
> ```

At more than three orders of magnitude slower than the old methods the new function is simply not appropriate for general use.  Hopefully it will be improved in a future release.

Comment: I really need a useful function that can parse a number or tell me that the input is not a number (and won't execute arbitrary code like ToExpression).  I also tried Interpreter and found it to be unusable slow, unfortunately (I can't wait for half a minute for a file to import).  I'm reporting the problem now and hoping for a fix ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I think `Read` is still your best bet.  What is the format or structure of the files you need to import?

Comment: `Read` is useful when the precise format is known in advance, i.e. you know what type of expect for the next token.  Take for example a mixture of strings and number.  If reading as a number fails, read as a string.  This comment wasn't motivated by the need to read a single file type only.

Comment: @Szabolcs I understand that; [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1739/121) is still applicable, as is `StringReplace`, depending on the specifics.  I'd welcome a Question from you on the subject.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've added an answer to this question that might serve your purpose.

Answer (score 7):

*updated based on comment feedback*

One more approach, using LibraryLink. Create a C file called `strto.cpp` as follows:

```c
#include <cstdlib>
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int wolfram_strtol(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  char *string;
  mint base;
  mint result;
  string = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
  base = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
  result = strtol(string, NULL,base);
  MArgument_setInteger(Res,result);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int wolfram_strtod(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  char *string;
  mint base;
  mreal result;
  string = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
  result = strtod(string, NULL);
  MArgument_setReal(Res,result);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

This is a very thin wrapper for the C++ `strtol` and `strtod` standard library functions.

Create the library:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
lib = CreateLibrary[{"wolfram_strto.cpp"}, "wolfram_strto"]
```

Load the two library functions:

```
strtol = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "wolfram_strtol", {"UTF8String", Integer}, Integer];
strtod = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "wolfram_strtod", {"UTF8String"}, Real];
```

Test the basics:

```
strtol["104", 10]
```

This should return the integer 104

```
strtod["10e4"]
```

This should return the real 100000.

Check some harder cases:

```
strtod /@ {"3.14159", "3.14159e-02", "3.14159e+02", "1.23e-5", "1E6", "1.734E-003", "2.12e1"}
```

Try a hex number:

```
strtol["0x2AF3", 0]
```

This should return 10995 (e.g. same as `16^^2AF3`)

Measure the elapsed time to 15,000 randomly generated reals:

```
strings = ToString @ Row[ RandomChoice /@ {{"-", ""}, {#}, {"e"}, {"-", ""}, Range@12}] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 10}, 15000]
First@AbsoluteTiming[ strtod /@ strings]
```

Returns in about 0.017 seconds on my machine.

For big numbers, there is another difference:

```
Internal`StringToDouble["1e4000"]
strtod["1e4000"]
```

The `StringToDouble` function gives `$Failed["IEEE Exception"]` and the `strtod` function gives `DirectedInfinity[1]`.

In the case of underflow you get, respectively, `$Failed["IEEE Underflow"]` and `0.`

Also, `StringToDouble` recognizes WL notation (e.g. 6.022*^23) and `strtod` does not recognize this format.

Comment: source code here: https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/wolfram-librarylink-examples/tree/master/01-BasicExamples/02-Strings/StringToNumber

Comment: My C compiler's `strtod` is a two-argument function (no `base` argument). (+1)

Comment: It indeed has only two arguments in any standard-conforming C compiler, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtod).

Comment: It's correct in the github code (I had the same problem, but I did find some version of it which wanted three arguments...)

Comment: I guess there is more than one variant here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol

Comment: ok, I've updated the post to use a (hopefully) more compliant `#include <cstdlib>` on Windows (together with a switch to the C++ compiler, which is more compliant on Windows)

Comment: I have another LibraryLink implementation here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118402/12  The biggest problem with `StringToDouble` is that it cannot indicate that the string does not represent a number (not that it's internal).

Answer (score 6):

May be one can try the following

```
convert[inp_?StringQ] := ToExpression@StringReplace[inp, "e" -> "*10^"];
```

Comment: Still this is not fully correct! If numbers like 2.12 is represented as "2.12e" than the expected "2.12e1". MMA does so as I mentioned in the above comment on the answer given by @J.M

Comment: It works, but let me give one comment: whenever you use `ToExpression` on *data* read from a file, you make it possible to inject code into a program even inadvertently (one can never tell what sort of erroneous input the program might get by mistake).  I generally try not to use `ToExpression` for just reading in data (as opposed to converting code)

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for explaining the issue with `ToExpression`. Your implementation is pretty cool. I did not know about the function `StringToStream` thanks for introducing...

Comment: You can actually replace `"*10^"` with `"*^"`, which would be the Mathematica's syntax for floating-point exponents. E.g. `InputForm[N[5^-9]]` will give you `5.12*^-7` as the output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mathematica function which accepts a string and return a number or a string containing an error message.

```
ConvertScientificNumberStringToNumber[string_String] := Block[
   {regexSciNum, regexNumOnly, regexNumEOnly},
   regexSciNum = "^ *(\\+|-)?(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+)((e|E)((\\+|-)?\\d+)?)? *$";
   regexNumOnly = "^ *(\\+|-)?(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+) *$";
   regexNumEOnly = "^ *(\\+|-)?(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+)(e|E) *$";
   If[! StringMatchQ[string, RegularExpression[regexSciNum]],
     Return["String is not a valid Scientific Format Number"];
   ];
   If[ StringMatchQ[string, RegularExpression[regexNumOnly]],
     Return[ToExpression[string]];
   ];
   If[ StringMatchQ[string, RegularExpression[regexNumEOnly]],
     (* If nothing appears after e|E then We need to strip everything after e|E *)
     Return[ToExpression[StringReplace[string, RegularExpression["(e|E)(.+)?$"] -> ""]]]
   ,
     Return[ ToExpression[StringReplace[string, RegularExpression["(e|E)"] -> "*^"]]]
   ];
   Return["Error we should not reach this point in the function."];
];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with large data (1E6 points) in Ver 8.0.1:

```
test = Import["scope_29_1.csv", "Data"];
test2 = ToExpression[Drop[test, 2]];
```

"Data" forces mathematica to convert 1.734E-003 into 0.001734 but keeps as string because the first 2 lines contains names.
"Drop" Keeps the first non-numerical lines out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ToExpression@StringReplace[s, "e" -> "*10^"]
```