# Importing and manipulating strings - time data

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, date-and-time

I have a list of time durations, which are strings of the form: `"hh:mm:ss"`. Here's a sample for you to play with:

```
durations = {"00:09:54", "00:31:24", "00:40:07", "00:11:58", "00:13:51", "01:02:32"}
```

I want to convert all of these into numbers in seconds, so that I can actually do useful things with this data!

How would I go about doing this? There must be some way to get *Mathematica* to extract the relevant things from each string.

Thanks.

Edit: I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a question related to this already - but it may be that I was using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method based on `AbsoluteTime`:

```
AbsoluteTime /@ durations - AbsoluteTime["00:00:00"]
(* {594, 1884, 2407, 718, 831, 3752} *)
```

Comment: Although this produces correct answers, probably it would be adherent to the current Wolfram Language date & time toolset to do `QuantityMagnitude[TimeObject /@ durations - TimeObject[{0}], "Seconds"]` - where `TimeObject`s don't get dates assigned to them, and where you could also control the measurement unit in a more obvious manner.

Answer (score 5):

One method:

```
3600 FromDMS[ToExpression[StringSplit[#, ":"]]] & /@ durations
   {594, 1884, 2407, 718, 831, 3752}
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify that performance is important but I decided to examine that aspect.

First I generate a list of 10,000 durations:

```
durations = 
  ToString@Row[#, ":"] & /@ 
   Map[IntegerString[#, 10, 2] &, 
    RandomInteger[{0, 24}, {10000, 3}], {2}];
```

I then time each of the existing solutions (using `timeAvg`, posted many times before):

```
AbsoluteTime /@ durations - AbsoluteTime["00:00:00"] // timeAvg
```

> 7.722

```
3600 FromDMS[ToExpression[StringSplit[#, ":"]]] & /@ durations // timeAvg
```

> 0.078

We see that at least with my test set and on my machine the second method is more than two orders of magnitude faster than the first, but I think we can do better:

```
FromDigits[#, 60] & /@ Map[FromDigits, StringSplit[durations, ":"], {2}] // timeAvg
```

> 0.02868

By using the undocumented function [`StringToDouble`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/121) we can eek out a bit more:

```
timeAvg[
  FromDigits[#, 60] & /@ Map[Internal`StringToDouble, StringSplit[durations, ":"], {2}]
]
```

> 0.02248

This last method returns Reals instead of Integers, if that matters, but the time taken to `Round` is negligible:

```
seconds = 
  FromDigits[#, 60] & /@ Map[Internal`StringToDouble, StringSplit[durations, ":"], {2}];

Round[seconds] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00011488