# I want to import a .csv to Mathematica but when I do that the decimal are denoted by ",". What can I do? I need points

Tags: plotting

Import["C:\Users\Maria Del Mar\Desktop\LECCIÓN\masa a.csv", 
  "table", FieldSeparators -> ";"] // TableForm

Comment: Did you try FieldSeparators->","

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the decimal point using the `Numberpoint` option, like described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14335/19176):

```
Import["file.txt", "Table", "NumberPoint" -> ","]
```