# Reading in scientific notation from C++ to Mathematica

Tags: import, inputfield

With a text file with entries formatted as (output from C++):

```
f[38.67] = -2.5387862698183892298317350539374412777263289550697e-05;
⋮
```

Is there a way to read this into *Mathematica*? It seems to be getting confused with the `e`, thinking it is just a symbol `e`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma

Comment: When reading Python output in the past I have once or twice done a global replacement of `e` with `*^`. That seems like the easiest approach if you have this file already in place.

Comment: Could be, is there an automated way to get Mathematica to do this? I am going to have lots of files in this format..(I was thinking about changing the output of c++ code to non scientific but it's not too easy with the MPFR data type and c++ wrapper I am using)

Comment: Alternatively, you could `Get` the file via a pipe, preprocessing it with `sed` or similar.

Comment: How would I go about that? sorry

Comment: Perhaps something like `<<"!sed 's/e/*^/gI' < file.m"`? Obviously you should be careful when doing this if you have other occurrences of "e" in the file.

Comment: Try ``Internal`StringToDouble``

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similar to Rolf's method:

```
string = "f[38.67]=-2.5387862698183892298317350539374412777263289550697e-05;";

StringReplace[string, {"e+" :> "*^", "e-" :> "*^-"}];

ToExpression@%;

?? f
```

> ```
> Global`f
>
> f[38.67] = -0.000025387862698183892298317350539374412777263289550697
> ```

Depending on your data you may want a more specific pattern, e.g.:

```
StringReplace[string,
  {a : NumberString ~~ "e" ~~ b : NumberString :> a <> "*^" <> b}]
```

Comment: Regex fun: `StringReplace[string, RegularExpression["e([+-]?)(\\d+)"] :> "*^$1$2"]`

Comment: @J.M. you are a glutton for punishment, aren't you!

Comment: @Oleksandr... but I **like** regexes! :D Also, I like the generality: it can handle all of `"2.9e5"`, `"1.7e+2"`, and `"3.16e-3"`.

Answer (score 5):

`Import` usually automatically converts the e format to powers of. You can use `ImportString` with the `"Table"` or `"List"` type:

```
ImportString["-2.5387862698183892298317350539374412777263289550697e-05", "Table"]
```

> {{-0.000025387862698183892298317350539374412777263289550697}}

or

```
ImportString["1.002e-26", "Table"]
```

> {{1.002*10^-26}}

Comment: thanks, but what if I want the input to initialize this function `f` rather than just reading the RHS values and putting them in a list?

Comment: I had previously just been using `Get` to do this.

Answer (score 4):

For those wishing to transform a full data file with numbers in scientific notation that is output from Fortran (or C, et al.) as `"1.6E-19"` and `"3.0E+08"` and such, it is incredibly faster to make changes in the Unix `sed` command line editor than doing a search and replace in the .m file within Mathematica or any word processor.  At the Unix prompt `$` one types

```bash
$ cat FilewE.m | sed 's/E-/*^-/g' | sed 's/E+/*^+/g' > FilewoE.m
```

For those new to Unix, the `cat` command "concatenates" a single file (named `FilewE.m` in this example), which normally would flow the contents onto the terminal screen.  Instead the flow is piped `|` into `sed` and, to avoid killing off any `E`s that appear in words,  `E-` is replaced with `*^-` globally `g`.  The output of that is piped into `sed` again to catch the positive exponents and the output of that is directed `>` to the output file named `FilewoE.m` in this example.

Comment: This should be the answer especially if you are dealing with a lot of files.  Easily incorporated in a script.