# How to convert a string of number into real numbers without precision loss

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion, precision-and-accuracy

I searched and did not find similar answers which can resolve the 'no precision loss' issue. A sample string is:

```
"-5.100686209408900133332e+02 -1.294005398404007344443e+01 -2.59376479781563728887e+02 -1.3043629998334040122222e+02"
```

If I immediately convert them into real variable by `ImportString` or `StringToDouble`, then there will be precision loss, the resulted precision is only `$MachinePrecision`.

How to convert them into real number which should have higher precision than `$MachinePrecision`.

Comment: what is `StringToDouble` ?

Comment: @Nasser : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/121

Comment: Related: [(15051)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15051/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question feels familiar but I could not find a true duplicate.

You can use the string replacement that Oleksandr proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma/1744#comment28110_9643) and then use `ToExpression` to convert the numbers:

```
string = "-5.100686209408900133332e+02 -1.294005398404007344443e+01 \
-2.59376479781563728887e-02 -1.3043629998334040122222e+02"

ToExpression /@ StringReplace[StringSplit@string, "e" | "E" :> "*^"]
```

> ```
> {-510.068620940890013333, -12.94005398404007344443, -0.025937647978156372889,
>  -130.43629998334040122222}
> ```

---

*Edit: a bug in verison 9 prevents the following solution from working.*

Better I think, avoiding accidential code evaluation from `ToExpression`, you can use `Read` or `ReadList` with type `Number`, as I proposed for [How do you convert a string containing a number in C scientific notation to a Mathematica number?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma/1739#1739):

```
# &[ReadList[#, Number], Close@#]& @ StringToStream @ string
```

> ```
> {-510.068620940890013333, -12.94005398404007344443, -0.025937647978156372889,
>  -130.43629998334040122222}
> ```

Note that `# &[body, cleanup]` is simply a way to evaluate `cleanup` after `body`, then return `body`.

Comment: However, the further command causes: error message: `General::digit: "Digit at position 1 in \!\(\"-5.100686209408900133332\"\) is too large to be used in base 10. "'

Comment: @LCFactorization Please, what code causes that error?

Comment: `# &[ReadList[#, Number], Close@#]& @ StringToStream @ string` will casue such error; others are OK.

Comment: @LCF With what input? (What is assigned to `string`?)  Which version are you using?  I have not yet seen the error you describe.

Comment: I use exactly the same `string = "-5.100686209408900133332e+02 -1.294005398404007344443e+01 \
-2.59376479781563728887e-02 -1.3043629998334040122222e+02"'; the error persists

Comment: @LCFactorization Okay, it must be a version difference.  I'll see if I can get someone to look at that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Probably this might be the reason

Comment: Yes, this is a version difference. It stops working in version 9. I suspect a bug since the errors do not make sense and a very strange output is produced (`{100*Removed["$$Failure"], 10*Removed["$$Failure"], Removed["$$Failure"]/100, 100*Removed["$$Failure"]}`).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have same problem and using above mentioned code, I still get only till MachinePrecision in Mathematica v9.0, is there some improvement you can suggest?I cannot find anything anywhere about this topic.

Comment: @jason does the `StringReplace` code at the top work correctly?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no it does not. It still gives me only MachinePrecision values

Answer (score 4):

The following is a place to start:
 Use `StringToStream` to convert the string data to an input stream:

```
num = "-5.100686209408900133332e+02 -1.294005398404007344443e+01
-2.59376479781563728887e+02 -1.3043629998334040122222e+02"
```

Now

```
str = StringToStream[num];
```

Use `ReadList` to read the `InputStream`

```
data = ReadList[str, Table[Record, {4}], RecordSeparators -> {" "}]; Close[str];
```

Here's the main trick to get your high precision `Real`

```
ReleaseHold[ToExpression[data, InputForm, Hold] /. {Plus[Times[x_, E | e], y_] :> x*10^y}]
```

Which gives:

```
{{-510.068620940890013333, -12.94005398404007344443, -259.37647978156372889,
 -130.43629998334040122222}}
```

Comment: I believe that there are simpler alternatives to this, as shown in my answer.  Can you give any reason to use this more elaborate method?

Comment: Though this answer works, I am curious why there is so such command as `close` the Stream...

Comment: @LCFactorization closing the stream is [important](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion); see my answer for simple code to do this.

Comment: And there is such error messsage : ToExpression::notstr: The format type InputForm is valid only for string input

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no reason, just that I'm used to manipulating different file formats and this was what came to mind first.

Comment: @LCFactorization, your example shows a string input, am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you . This answer can also work if the thus obtained `data` be converted by `First@ImportString[#, 
  "List"]` elementwise