# How to read non-standard-format data into Mathematica from a file

Tags: import, data, files-and-directories, data-format

I would like to read non-standard-format data into Mathematica from a file. How can this be achieved? For example, how can I read the following text file of data into Mathematica:

```
(8.675e-11+3.881e-11j) (7.775e-11+3.815e-11j) (0.675e-11+3.385e-11j)
(2.675e-11+3.889e-11j) (7.075e-11+3.835e-11j) (3.675e-11+3.815e-11j)
(0.675e-11+3.886e-11j) (7.975e-11+3.875e-11j) (7.675e-11+3.885e-11j)
(1.675e-11+3.828e-11j) (7.275e-11+3.185e-11j) (1.675e-11+3.805e-11j)
```

To explain, the first entry should be entered as the complex number $8.675 \times 10^{-11} + i (3.881 \times 10^{-11})$.

Comment: Any code you are working on ?

Comment: I would look at `StringCases` and see if I can extract the data using string patterns of regular expressions.  It won't be fast or suitable for huge files but it should be possible.  As a start read in the data using Import[..., "List" or "Table" or "String"] then StringSplit, finally use StringCases to structure it and ToExpression to convert the pieces to numbers.

Comment: Related: [(1737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/121),
[(15051)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15051/121),
[(38952)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38952/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For large files using `ReadList` is the way to go. So if we assume the name of your file is "file.txt", then the following should be efficient:

```
StringReplace[#, {"e" -> "*^", "j" -> "I"}] & /@ 
      ReadList["file.txt", Word, WordSeparators -> {"(", ")", " "}, 
       RecordLists -> True] // ToExpression
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `StringReplace`:

```
text = "(8.675e-11+3.881e-11j) (7.775e-11+3.815e-11j) (0.675e-11+3.385e-11j)
        (2.675e-11+3.889e-11j) (7.075e-11+3.835e-11j) (3.675e-11+3.815e-11j)
        (0.675e-11+3.886e-11j) (7.975e-11+3.875e-11j) (7.675e-11+3.885e-11j)
        (1.675e-11+3.828e-11j) (7.275e-11+3.185e-11j) (1.675e-11+3.805e-11j)"


ToExpression[
  StringReplace[#, {"e" -> "*^", "j" -> "I", "(" -> "", ")" -> ""}]] & /@
  ImportString[text, "Table"]
```