# Data manipulation in Mathematica

Tags: import

I have a very big data set that I have generated in Matlab. I am importing into Mathematica since doing some data manipulation is much easier.

There is one caveat, which is the following: I have some data entries that appear as the string

```
"0.677 + 9.121e-12i"
```

or

```
"1.247e-12 + 0.182i"
```

where `e-12` is actually the exponential of -12 (i.e. very small). Due to the formatting of the exponential, Mathematica does not recognise it as an exponential. Hence, I want to set any term that contains e to be 0 such that for the two entries above, I get:

```
"0.677"
"0.182i"
```

I am then able to use `ToExpression` to recast the whole data set to something that I can further manipulate.

Comment: Related: [Reading in scientific notation from C++ to Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/reading-in-scientific-notation-from-c-to-mathematica)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following operator:

```
op = ToExpression@*StringReplace[{"e+" -> "*^", "e-" -> "*^-", "i" -> "I"}]
```

which can then be applied to strings of numbers:

```
op["0.677 + 9.121e-12i"]
op["1.247e-12 + 0.182i"]
```

Comment: Can this be applied to a matrix of strings?

Comment: i.e. currently, I have to apply it recursively on each element of the matrix. Any better way to do this?

Comment: @Sid, try `Map[op, mat, {2}]`

Comment: I would throw a `Chop` in `op` to get rid of the small terms and produce the wanted results.