# ReadList with type Expression unable to read scientific notation?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a file that defines an array of numbers like this:

```
freq["AQs"] = 8.846947803007962E-4
...
```

I am reading the file with `ReadList["myfile.txt", Expression]` but Mathematica reads the above entry as `20.0` `instead of 0.000884695`.

How can I read the array correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem lies in the E . In Mathematica, E presents the exponential constant e. In your case, ReadList gets the result of 8.846947803007962 times E minus 4

Comment: I'd read this file as strings, use `StringReplace` to change the E in `*10^` and then use `ToExpression` to convert it to an expression.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries `Internal\`StringToDouble` will also convert numbers in this format. Also I would note that many people would not consider this to be an example of scientific notation; rather it is a notation used in some programming languages.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Good to know, but generally I try to avoid using undocumented internal functions if it's easy to do so. In this case, one would not even need Mathematica. A simple find and replace in a text editor would do.

Comment: @ Oleksandr R. You are right.  This numbers are produced by a different programming language and they are the external representation of a 'double' real.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/121