# ToExpression and Fortran notation

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, fortran

```
ToExpression["9.0E-03"]
```

interprets the string as

```
9*e - 3
```

instead of what I am expecting:

```
0.009
```

How can I convert the expression to fortran notation?

Comment: `ToExpression[StringReplace["9.0E-03", "E" -> "*^"]]`

Comment: @rasher thank you!

Comment: essential duplicate http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/2079

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ImportString`, with the "Table" or "List" argument. See the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImportString.html) for details.

```
ImportString["9.0E-03", "Table"]

(* {{0.009}} *)
```

or

```
ImportString["9.0E-03", "List"]

(* {0.009} *)
```

Comment: thank you! I'm a bit puzzled though with Mathematica's architecture: why is it a separate function and moreover contains Import in its title?

Comment: ImportString takes a String as argument and provides the same output as Import, which takes a file as Argument.

Answer (score 7):

The given above answer is correct, however if you are not against using undocumented functions, then

```
Internal`StringToDouble["9.0E-03"]
```

is much faster.

To demonstrate the speedup, first generate some fake data

```
heads = ToString /@ 
    RandomReal[{1.0000, 9.9999}, 100000, WorkingPrecision -> 5] // Quiet;
exp = ConstantArray["E-", 100000];
tails = ToString /@ RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 100000];
strings = MapThread[StringJoin, {heads, exp, tails}]
lines = ExportString[strings, "List"];
```

So `strings` is a list of strings in the form of `"1.3452E-5"` and `lines` is one big string with each number in the same format separated with a newline. The two options are:

```
Internal`StringToDouble /@ strings // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> ```
> {0.0408109,{2.0525*10^-9,7.983*10^-7,<<99997>>,0.000099743}}
> ```

and

```
ImportString[lines, "List"] // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> ```
> {0.626226,{2.0525*10^-9,7.983*10^-7,<<99997>>,0.000099743}}
> ```

If you have the choice of input format (list of strings or strings with newlines), then `` Internal`StringToDouble `` is 15 times faster.

Finally, `ReadList` is useful to juggle the string formats. First option:

```
Internal`StringToDouble /@ ReadList[StringToStream[lines], String] // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> ```
> {0.0808349,{2.0525*10^-9,<<99998>>,0.000099743}}
> ```

That is to say, `ReadList[StringToStream[lines], String]` is much faster in converting the string with linebreaks to a list of strings than `ImportString[lines, "List"]`. Additionally, to test everything "for real":

```
Export["test.dat", lines, "String"] (* this takes a while, but we're 
                                       planning to import, not export *)
Internal`StringToDouble /@ ReadList["test.dat", String] // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> ```
> {0.0769682,{2.0525*10^-9,7.983*10^-7,<<99997>>,0.000099743}}
> ```

Comment: If importing a file with 5 numbers per row and ~11K rows (so, 5500 calls), this is the only way to go (with respect to answers on this page).  Though the other answer does work and is feasible for small computations. +1