# Convert a string into a list of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, conversion

I got the following problem I don't know how to solve or if it's at all possible to solve(I'm quite new to *Mathematica* and don't have an IT background, so please explain slowly if possible:))

I'm trying to convert a simple string which I imported from a homepage into a list of numbers. 
The string looks for example the following:

```
{"1,2,3,5,10,12,13,17,26,30,32,41,42,43,113,115,121,125"}
```

*Mathematica* sees this as one string, this is important, not as a list of strings. (I used the head function to check that)

My question: is it possible to convert this one string into a list of numbers so that each number in the string above is recognized as an individual element and can be calculated with?

Another important note: these strings don't all contain the same amount of numbers, a couple of them are shorter than other ones.

Is there any way I can convert these different strings into lists of numbers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
str = {"1,2,3,5,10,12,13,17,26,30,32,41,42,43,113,115,121,125"}

Flatten@ToExpression@StringSplit[str, ","]
```

Short explanation:

After executing `StringSplit` you get a list of separated "StringNumbers" like

> {{"1", "2", ... "125"}}

`ToExpression` converts these "StringNumbers" to Integers. `Flatten` removes the outermost brackets. You can even omit `Flatten` by looking at gpap's comment. This works for lists of varying lengths and also for different number types.

**EDIT**

To also answer the question in your comment:

```
eq = {{"1", "3", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2", "4", "7"}, {"1", "3"}};

ToExpression[Flatten /@ Map[StringSplit[#, ","] &, eq]]
```

Comment: beat me to it! You can use the shorter `ToExpression@@StringSplit[str,","]`

Comment: This works perfect, thanks for the very quick answering guys:) I have one more question regarding the same subject: I have a list of these strings that looks the following: eq={{1,3,5,6},{1,2,4,7,10,11},{1,3,4,5,7}}. Is it somehow possible to convert these strings into numbers all at once or do I have to convert each string in the eq-list separately?:)

Comment: upvote for explanation (however simple it must be to someone with 12.6k creds.) Too often all one gets is something incomprehensible to all but Mathematica-experts.

Answer (score 11):

I would use `ImportString` myself:

```
string = "1,2,3,5,10,12,13,17,26,30,32,41,42,43,113,115,121,125";

ImportString[string, "CSV"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 12, 13, 17, 26, 30, 32, 41, 42, 43, 113, 115, 121, 125}}
> ```

Are you using *Mathematica* for the operation *which I imported from a homepage*?  There may be a more direct method in that case.

---

Regarding your comment:

> I have a list of these strings that looks the following: eq={{1,3,5,6},{1,2,4,7,10,11},{1,3,4,5,7}}. Is it somehow possible to convert these strings into numbers all at once or do I have to convert each string in the eq-list separately?:)

The fastest way I am aware of uses an internal function I described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9643/121).  It is not error-tolerant so make sure your data is as you describe or it may crash the Kernel.  A quick example of use:

```
eq = {{"1", "3", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2", "4", "7", "10", "11"}, {"1", "3", "4", "5", "7"}};

System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable[eq, {{{}, {}}, {"-", "+"}, "."}, False]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 11}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}}
> ```

See the linked answer for an explanation of the parameters.

---

If you prefer not to use the error-intolerant and undocumented `ParseTable` you can as [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst) reminds make direct use of `ToExpression`:

```
ToExpression @ eq
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 11}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}}
> ```

This is however more than an order of magnitude slower than `ParseTable`.

Comment: For your second part, can't you just do `ToExpression[eq]`?

Comment: @ChipHurst Yes you can, but as I said it is not "the fastest way" which is what I was attempting to offer. `ParseTable` is more than an order of magnitude faster on this kind of data.  (v10 timings.)

Comment: Got it, and yes it's touchy, my kernel crashed too. :-)

Comment: @ChipHurst I incorporated your implicit suggestion into this answer, with credit of course.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative method:

```
list = {"1,2,3,5,10,12,13,17,26,30,32,41,42,43,113,115,121,125"};

StringCases[#, x : NumberString :> ToExpression @ x] & /@  list
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 12, 13, 17, 26, 30, 32, 41, 42, 43, 113, 115, 121, 125}}
> ```

Or

```
ToExpression["{" <> # <> "}"] & /@ list
```

Comment: Even playing with `Trace` I couldn't figure out how your last one  works. But it works.

Comment: @eldo well, this is ugly strightforward way: `"1, 2" -> "{1, 2}" -> {1, 2}`

Answer (score 5):

With **V10** one can also do

```
str = "4.5e2, 0.08, 5, 10";

Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Number"]][str] // Flatten
```

> {450., 0.08, 5, 10}

Or even

```
str = "4.5e2, 0.08, 5, 10, one, one divided by forty-eight";

Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["SemanticExpression"]][str] // Flatten //InputForm
```

> {450., 0.08, 5, 10, 1, 1/48}

Comment: `Interpreter` can be very slow; `SemanticImportString` may be a better choice.  See: [(57865)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57865)

Answer (score 4):

For completeness sake, another solution:

```
str = "1,2,3,5,10,12,13,17,26,30,32,41,42,43,113,115,121,125";
FromDigits /@ StringSplit[str, ","]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str={"1,2,3,5,10,12,13,17,26,30,32,41,42,43,113,115,121,125"}

ToExpression[StringCases[str[[1]], DigitCharacter ..]]

ToExpression[StringSplit[str[[1]], ","]]

ToExpression["{" ~~ str[[1]] ~~ "}"]
```