# How to replace a space by a comma

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, string-manipulation

in this `expression = "{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}"`, I want to replace each space by a comma `,` to get `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.`

Comment: Try this. `expression = "{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}"; ToExpression@StringSplit[
 StringReplace[expression, "{" | "}" -> ""]]`

Comment: @PlatoManiac, thanks for your answer!

Comment: related: [50403](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50403/5478)

Comment: `ImportString[StringReplace["{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}", "{" | "}" -> ""], "List", "LineSeparators" -> " "]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
expression = "{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}";
```

A few alternatives to PlatoManiac's approach:

```
ToExpression[
    expression, 
    StandardForm, 
    Function[e, Sequence @@@ Unevaluated[e], HoldAll]
]
```

or

```
ToExpression @ StringReplace[expression, " " -> ","]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

or

```
 StringCases[expression, n : NumberString :> ToExpression[n]]

 ToExpression @ StringCases[expression, NumberString]
```

Answer (score 10):

A possibility with `WhitespaceCharacter`

```
ToExpression@
     StringReplace[expression, WhitespaceCharacter -> ","]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} *)
```

Another using `Interpreter`

```
Interpreter[
   DelimitedSequence["Integer", {"{", " ", "}"}]][expression]
```

Answer (score 8):

My thought was to drop the brackets using `StringTake` and then import it using `ImportString`

```
"{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}"~StringTake~{2, -2}~ImportString~"Table" // First
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} *)
```

**edit** I just realized this is very similar to what J.M. suggested in his comment (although I'm playing around with infix notation here).

Comment: It's not *so* similar to JMs version and in fact, I was going to post exactly this solution, because I think it is noteworthy that a space-separated list of numbers can be imported as "Table". +1

Comment: Thanks, it was my first thought since I'm regularly running python (or c or fortran) code that outputs a big list or matrix and the quickest way for me to plot it is to just copy it and paste it into an `ImportString` command.

Answer (score 6):

Since space is implicit `Times` similar methods to [Convert head Times to List](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7836/121) can be applied:

```
Block[{Times = List}, ToExpression @ "{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}"] // First
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

Though in this case a much shorter method works too:

```
ToHeldExpression[expression] ~Level~ {3}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, inspired by Kuba's first one:

```
Sequence @@@ ToExpression[expression, StandardForm, Inactivate]
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar case to `"{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}"`, that also appears when you extract data from txt, is `{"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"}`

In  that case, one can use

```
ToExpression@ StringSplit@ {"1 2 3 4 5 6"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html):

```
ToExpression[StringRiffle[StringSplit["{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}"], ","]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

Note that `StringRiffle` can also perform the inverse operation too:

```
StringRiffle[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {"{", ", ", "}"}]
```

> ```
> "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Composition` :

```
strToList = Composition[
  ToExpression,
  StringSplit,
  StringReplace[#,
    PunctuationCharacter :> ""] &
  ];

alist = strToList@expression
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

---

Alternate notation:

```
ToExpression @*
  StringSplit@*(StringReplace[#, 
     PunctuationCharacter :> ""] &)@expression
```