# Convert data types from string to list (Coastal Buoy data) for DateListPlot

Tags: list-manipulation, import, date-and-time

I downloaded [**Coastal buoy data**](http://www.ndbc.l.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46218.txt) from the [CDIP webpages](https://cdip.ucsd.edu/) and saved it as a text file. The trouble is that the data has spaces between the YYY MM DD hh mm.

{**Edit 4/5/2019:** Updated [link](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46218.txt)  Please see comment below}

With `FileNames` and `Import`, I was able to import the data from a text file.

```
fn = FileNames["*.txt"]; (*I am interested in the first text file in this list*)
h2018 = Import[fn[[1]], "Data"]
```

What I want to do is convert the first 5 columns to `DateList` and then plot the 9th column against this new DateList.

I tried doing this to no effect because I am trying to convert the data to a string and then replacing spaces in the new string with `/` and then using `DateList`.

```
StringReplace[ToString[h2018[[3 ;;, 1 ;; 3]]], "," .. -> "/"];
StringReplace[%, " " -> ""];
dl=DateList[%];
```

**How do I convert this string to a DateList and complete my plotting of column 9 in `h2018` with the DateList, `dl`?**

I did try to convert this string to a list of numbers using the information in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50403/convert-a-string-into-a-list-of-numbers) but without success.

```
Flatten@ToExpression@StringSplit[%];
```

Comment: Link to txt file no longer works. [This](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46218.txt) works.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thank you! I have updated the question with your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the functions in the [Date & Time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DateAndTime.html) guide to manipulate dates. This step-by-step answer.

Import the table.

```
raw = Import["http://www.ndbc.l.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46218.txt", "Table"];
```

Notice that Mathematica has imported the numbers as numbers and not as strings.  Look at row 3 and columns from the start to column 5.

```
Head /@ raw[[3, ;; 5]]
```

> ```
> {Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer}
> ```

First collapse the 5 column headers for the date-times in row 1 and 2.  This is not strictly needed but will keep the headers consistent with the data.

```
raw[[;; 2]] = Flatten@MapAt[StringJoin, 1]@TakeDrop[#, 5] & /@ raw[[;; 2]];
```

Next feed the values in the first 5 columns into [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html).  The columns are in the exact order that `DateObject` expects so there is no need to adjust their positions. This is performed on row 3 until the end.

```
raw[[3 ;;]] = Flatten@MapAt[DateObject, 1]@TakeDrop[#, 5] & /@ raw[[3 ;;]];
```

Since the first 5 columns have been collapsed into 1 the information is now in column 5 instead of column 9, (`9 - 5 + 1`).  Take from row 3 until the end and columns 1 and 5 to plot with [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html).

```
DateListPlot[raw[[3 ;;, {1, 5}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
data = Import["http://www.ndbc.l.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46218.txt",
              "Table", HeaderLines -> 2][[All, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9}]];

ts = TimeSeries[Composition[Flatten, MapAt[DateObject, #, 1] &,
                            Reverse, TakeDrop[#, -1] &] /@ data];

DateListPlot[ts]
```

[image: plot of wave heights over time]

(If you don't want to convert to a `TimeSeries[]`, you can omit that part.)

---

Since the other answer has already been accepted, let me just illustrate how one might use the functionality of `Dataset[]` for this task:

```
data = Import["http://www.ndbc.l.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46218.txt", "Table"];
data = MapAt[StringReplace[#, "#" -> ""] &, Delete[data, 2], 1];
data = Dataset[AssociationThread[First[data], #] & /@ Rest[data]];

ds = <|"Timestamp" -> DateObject[{#YY, #MM, #DD, #hh, #mm}], 
       "WaveHeight" -> Quantity[#WVHT, "Meters"]|> & /@ data

Show[ds[DateListPlot, All], FrameLabel -> {None, "Wave Height (m)"}]
```

[image: labeled plot]

Comment: Woah! This seems to be fairly complex an operation.

Comment: Very interesting on the DataSet example.