# Convert matrix of strings to matrix of numbers

Tags: string-manipulation

I have 101 files each with a lot of data. from C output. (.out files) I have imported them to Mathematica 9. However, Mathematica reads the data from each file as an element of a table. So I used StringSplit, to split the data and it looks like this

```
{{{"425060", "0.214235E+07", "0.48", "0.01", "0.39", "0.49", "0.01", 
   "0.38", "1.64", "-1.65", "-2.13", "518"}, {"6650479", 
   "0.934695E+06", "0.48", "0.39", "0.43", "0.49", "0.39", "0.44", 
   "2.20", "-0.72", "0.51", "226"}, {"1248079", "0.153025E+07", 
   "0.04", "0.07", "0.30", "0.04", "0.07", "0.31", "-0.44", "-0.52", 
   "3.36", "370"}, {"4482147", "0.595558E+06", "0.39", "0.26", "0.38",
    "0.39", "0.28", "0.41", "0.95", "2.76", "5.47", "144"}, ......
```

My problem is with the `E+07` etc terms, when I try to convert this entire data to expressions, using `ToExpression`, Mathematica converts `E -> e=2.73` and evaluates the value. I have tried using `HoldForm` and `Hold` etc, however I do need those values to weed out a large portion of data. I have looked into `ImportString`, `StringReplace` etc options that were posted here, however they were for individual strings and not a list.

Comment: `s = {"425060", "0.214235E+07", "0.48", "0.01", "0.39", "0.49", "0.01", "0.38", "1.64", "-1.65", "-2.13", "518"};
Internal`StringToDouble[#] & /@ s`, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-do-you-convert-a-string-containing-a-number-in-c-scientific-notation-to-a-ma

Comment: Thanks, I read that post but I was discouraged by the statement " However, if you are trying to convert many such numbers at once, the standard, documented methods (Import, Read, etc.), are likely to represent better approaches. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `` Internal`StringToDouble ``:

```
Map[Internal`StringToDouble, {{"425060", "0.214235E+07", "0.48", 
   "0.01", "0.39", "0.49", "0.01", "0.38", "1.64", "-1.65", "-2.13", 
   "518"}, {"6650479", "0.934695E+06", "0.48", "0.39", "0.43", "0.49",
    "0.39", "0.44", "2.20", "-0.72", "0.51", "226"}, {"1248079", 
   "0.153025E+07", "0.04", "0.07", "0.30", "0.04", "0.07", "0.31", 
   "-0.44", "-0.52", "3.36", "370"}, {"4482147", "0.595558E+06", 
   "0.39", "0.26", "0.38", "0.39", "0.28", "0.41", "0.95", "2.76", 
   "5.47", "144"}}, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to apply this for a list of matrices? That's because my data is really a list of matrices, and I have about 100 of such matrices. So I tried Table[Map[Internal`StringToDouble, S[[i]], {2}], {i, 1, 100}], where S[[i]] are the matrices. Thanks.

Comment: @NilanjanBanik, no need for that. Just change `{2}` to `{3}` in my code but with your list of matrices.

Comment: @NilanjanBanik. My pleasure. Welcome to MMA.SE!