# NaNs in tabular data and import performance

Tags: performance-tuning, import

I'm working with some data files that are just too large for `Import`.

I tried using `ReadList`, specifying either `Number` or `Real` for all the columns, but this fails, because a few of the values in the data are NaNs, and are thus not considered numerical by Mathematica<sup>1</sup>.

I can get `ReadList` to work if I use `Record` as the types for all the columns, and the performance is not terrible (at least with the relatively small input files I'm using to prototype this import code), but the subsequent call to `ToExpression` is a performance killer.

I give a detailed example below, including timing data.

Any suggestions on how to get around this problem?

---

**ADDENDUM**

One promising possibility I discovered shortly after posting this question would be to define some input stream method `skipLinesWithNaNs` that (*somehow*) filters out the lines that contain NaNs.  Then I could just call

```
ReadList[OpenRead[pathToTSV, listOfNumericTypes, ...],
                  Method -> "skipLinesWithNaNs"];
```

...but I have not been able to figure out how to do this.  I'm sure it's not difficult, but I'm too sleep-deprived at the moment to see how to do it.  I guess my question may boil down to how to implement the `skipLinesWithNaNs` input stream method.  The difficulty, as I see it, is that input stream methods are byte-oriented (AFAICT), whereas the filtering I need done is best described, and easiest to implement, at the line level.  It would be great if *somewhere* in the ocean of *Mathematica* there was an adapter to convert a byte-oriented stream into a line-oriented one, but I have not yet found such...

---

**EDIT**

In response to episanty's request:

```
makeRow[ncols_, withNaNs_] := 
  If[withNaNs, 
   RandomSample[Prepend[makeRow[ncols - 1, False], "nan"]], 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, ncols]];

makeSampleInput[path_, nrows_, ncols_, nnans_] := 
  Export[path, 
   RandomSample[Table[makeRow[ncols, i <= nnans], {i, nrows}]], "TSV"];
```

Given these helper functions, one can use

```
makeSampleInput[pathToTSV, 40000, 400, 10];
```

to create a file at `pathToTSV` that is comparable to the input file I used for the **EXAMPLE** below.  Also, the following definition of the `types` parameter (which the **EXAMPLE** refers to) is consistent with the sample input file.

```
types = Table["Real", {400}];
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

First some setup:

```
fmt = StringTemplate["`1` s\t`2`"];
printTime[expr_] := Module[{timing, value},
   {timing, value} = AbsoluteTiming[expr];
   Print[fmt[timing, ToString[HoldForm[expr]]]];
   value
   ];
SetAttributes[printTime, HoldFirst];
tab = "\t";
nl = "\n";
```

Now, a data import sequence, as described at the beginning of this post:

```
(* read in rows of "Records" (in this case, simple strings) from TSV file *)
strings = 
  ReadList[pathToTSV, Table[Record, {types}], 
    RecordSeparators -> {tab, nl}] // printTime;

(* determine the indices of the "NaN-free" rows *)
keep = Flatten[
    Position[strings,
             Except[{___, "nan", ___}], 1, Heads -> False]] // printTime;

(* extract the "NaN-free" rows from table of strings *)
keptStrings = strings[[keep, ;;]] // printTime;

(* convert remaining string values to numbers *)
rows = ToExpression[keptStrings] // printTime;
```

The output produced by the calls to `printTime` are shown below; the first column shows the timing results for the expression in the second column:

```
2.796349 s  ReadList[pathToTSV, Table[Record, {types}], RecordSeparators -> {tab, nl}]

0.37655 s   Flatten[Position[strings, Except[{___, nan, ___}], 1, Heads -> False]]

0.005952 s  strings[[keep,1 ;; All]]

42.976491 s ToExpression[keptStrings]
```

As you can see, the call to `ToExpression` just blows away the performance.

BTW, the size of the file used for this experiment is about one meg:

```
NumberForm[ByteCount[strings], DigitBlock -> 3]
==> 770,461,048
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Producing pre-processed versions of the input files to remove the NaNs would pose a whole host of complications with the rest of our pipeline, so it is out of the question.</sub>

Comment: Can you post samples of the files you're trying to import? What do you want Mathematica to do with the NaN entries?

Comment: @episanty: as the example I posted shows, I am discarding all the *lines* that contain NaNs.

Comment: @episanty: see the new **EDIT** section in my post.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to output the rows with no NaNs as numbers inside nested Lists?

Comment: You mentioned line-oriented input: would [`ReadLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadLine.html) be of help in this case? It returns lines of input as strings; you would then be left with checking for NaN, then discarding or processing the vakd strings (maybe with `ImportString`?)

Comment: @episanty: yes, the output should be exactly the same that one would get from a call to `ReadList` on a version of the input file from which all the lines that mentioned `nan` had been filtered out.

Comment: @MarcoB: I have not tried `ReadLine`, but I imagine that it would suffer from exactly the same `ToExpression` bottleneck that I showed in my example.

Comment: What should be the value of the variable `types` in your sample code?

Comment: @MarcoB: `types` depends on the file contents; for the sample input file I proposed in the **EDIT**, `types = Table["Real", {400}]` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a simple solution, at least if `grep` or the like is available.  Here are the timing results when I apply to the file I used in my original post:

```
rows = 
  ReadList["!grep -iv nan " <> pathToTSV, types, 
    RecordSeparators -> {tab, nl}] // printTime;

3.72033 s   ReadList[!grep -v nan <> pathToTSV, types, RecordSeparators -> {tab, nl}]
```

One could generalize this idea to any type of pre-processing pipe (e.g. to weed out any line that contains anything other than numbers, not just NaNs), though, of course, all pre-processing incurs a performance cost.

Comment: This can work as well - it depends on where you want to put the data processing. If it's on the OS side you might as well do a pure preprocessing step, but there's probably something to be said for `grep`ping the data as it flows into Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this line by line, using the ability of [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html) to read a single record via its third argument. You can then check whether you want to keep that record, and `Sow` it if you do.

Thus, I would use something like this:

```
importFunction[path_, columns_, maxRows_:∞] := Block[
  {inputstream, record, i = 1},
  inputstream = OpenRead[path];
  Reap[
    While[
     i < maxRows,
     record = ReadList[inputstream, Table[Word, {columns}], 1];
     If[record === {}, Break[]];
     i++;
     If[
      FreeQ[record, "nan"],
      Sow[Internal`StringToDouble /@ First[record]]
      ]
     ];
    Close[inputstream]
    ][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

What this does:

- Opens the file as an `InputStream` object.
- Enters a `While` loop which will run over each line of the file.
- Reads `columns` words from the file at a time. This assumes the file is made up of `columns` numbers per line, separated with spaces. This record is stored in `record` as a list of strings.
- It then checks whether `record` is `FreeQ` of `"nan"`. If it is,
- it converts it to numbers via `` Internal`StringToDouble ``, as per [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/1000). This is mostly equivalent to `ToExpression` when the input is a number. Pro: it handles the notation `7.556e-4` correctly, which `ToExpression` does not. Con: it doesn't notice if it is not given a number, so `` Internal`StringToDouble["nan"] == 0 ``.
- If the record is empty, it `Break`s from the loop.

Given the input

```
makeSampleInput["~/Desktop/temp.tsv", 40000, 400, 10]
```

on my machine the timing is

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Dimensions[data = importFunction["~/Desktop/temp.tsv", 400]]
 ]

(* {14.3875, {39990, 400}} *)
```

I'm not sure how acceptable this is for your larger files. I'm afraid I can't compare it with your code as it returns the error `Table::iterb: "Iterator {types} does not have appropriate bounds. "`.

Comment: Thanks, I found reading your code instructive.  I did find a pretty good solution, though.  Both fast and simple.  I just posted it.  I think it's the way to go, at least when running under a "Unixy" OS.  (There's got to be an equivalent move for Windows, but I know very little about that OS.)

Comment: You might find tip 7 [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) interesting. I was under the impression that it also discouraged use of `Part` (which you use in your question to sort out the keepers from the nots), but it may not be that inefficient.

Comment: On the Mathematica side, you could simply try mapping ``Internal`StringToDouble`` over the appropriate level of the list in the code in the question.