# How to extract numeric value?

Tags: string-manipulation, units

Considering two situations:

I have a string `"F2.5"` and `Quantity["2.3s"]`. How can the numeric value be extracted to have:

```
"F2.5"` -> 2.5

Quantity["2.3s"]` -> 2.3
```

Thanks!

Comment: `QuantityMagnitude[Quantity["2.3", "Seconds"]]`

Comment: Why not simply drop the first character and use `ToExpression`?

Comment: @Julian you don't know if it is Seconds or other measurement unit

Comment: @YvesKlett what if the it is not "F2.5" but "2.5"F

Comment: `List @@ Quantity["2.3s"] // First`

Comment: First@(2.3 s)  yields 2.3

Comment: @thils you are right, it is even more direct !

Comment: Sorry for typo "F2.5" or "2.5F"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
StringDrop["F2.5", 1] // ToExpression

StringDrop["2.5F", -1] // ToExpression
```

and

```
List @@ Quantity["2.3s"] // First
```

or rather as **@thils** proposed, directly

```
Quantity["2.3s"] // First
```

Answer (score 5):

[`` Internal`StringToDouble ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/121) seems applicable:

```
Internal`StringToDouble /@ {"F2.5", "2.5F"}
```

> ```
> {2.5, 2.5}
> ```

The evaluated form of `Quantity["2.3s"]` is `` Quantity[2.3`,"Seconds"] `` therefore as already commented:

```
Quantity["2.3s"][[1]]
```

> ```
> 2.3
> ```

[`` System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9643/121) provides configurable options for processing strings.

Comment: Nice ! I was looking in the $ImportFormats but failed to find something useful ...

Comment: Do you know in which functions this internal is used ? This works: `ImportString["2.5F", "List"]` but it does not for "F2.5" ... `Interpreter["Number"]["F2.5"]` or `Interpreter["Number"]["2.5F"]` do not work either ...

Comment: @SquareOne I seem to recall coming across an explicit use of ``Internal`StringToDouble`` by a built-in function but I cannot recall where at the moment.  If I do later I'll let you know.

Answer (score 3):

This may be more robust, assuming you  want to see the specific letter "F":

```
 ToExpression@StringCases[ #,
        {"F" ~~ s : NumberString -> s, 
         s : NumberString ~~ "F" -> s}] & /@
             {"F3.14", "2.718F","an embedded number F2.34 in a string"}
```

> {{3.14}, {2.718}, {2.34}}