# Avoiding misconversion of data with ToExpression function

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, rule

I've got a list of [data](http://hastebin.com/cudesisezu.vala) with the following structure

[image: A snapshot of the data imported with matematica]

which can be easily converted To expresion by some manipulation such as

```
StringSplit[ToString[data], {"  ", "\n"}];

StringSplit[ToString[data[[1]]], {" ", "\n"}];
```

and I get the list i am interested on and its output:

```
mx = Table[ToExpression[data[[2 + 8*i]] ], {i, 1,Length[data]/8 - 1}];
```

> 0.0158183, 0.0158061, 0.0157933, 0.0157796, 0.0157652, 0.0157499, \
>   0.0157337, 0.0157165, 0.0156982, 0.0156788, 0.015658, 0.0156358, \
>   0.015612, 0.0155863, 0.0155583, 0.0156255 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 9.80429 e), 0.0155807 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 8.85353 e), 0.0155284 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 7.88611 e), 0.015463 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 6.90164 e), 0.0153814 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 5.91632 e), 0.0152822 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 4.94252 e), 0.0151678 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 3.98449 e), 0.0150438 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 3.04207 e), 0.0149143 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 2.11355 e), 0.0147807 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 1.19662 e), 0.0146437 + 
>    0.999848 (-6 - 2.90415 e), 0.0145031 + 
>    0.999848 (-6 + 6.0634 e), 0.0143595 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 1.49482 e), 0.0142126 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 2.37426 e), 0.0140625 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 3.24488 e), 0.0139089 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 4.1055 e), 0.0137518 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 4.95496 e), 0.0135908 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 5.78955 e), 0.0134258 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 6.60316 e), 0.0132566 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 7.39248 e), 0.0130828 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 8.13654 e), 0.0129038 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 8.72386 e), 0.0127163 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 8.76224 e), 0.0125254 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 9.86248 e), 0.0124538, 0.0113728, 0.0104582 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 8.81941 e), 0.00985979 + 
>    0.999848 (-6 - 3.81614 e), 0.00938305 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 6.02078 e), 0.00894878 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 - 8.67399 e), 0.00759501 + 
>    0.999848 (-5 + 
>       5.43005 e), -0.0157732, -0.0157874, -0.0158007, -0.0158133, \
>   -0.0158251

As you can see the data is not properly converted . Is there some easy way for a beginner to avoid this problem ?

Comment: By the way, The original data file It is a .txt that can be easily plotted with gnuplot but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: There's something funny about the way your question is formatted.  Can you clean it up a bit to make it more readable? You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `SemanticImportString` might solve your parsing problem.

Comment: You can write a newline as `"\n"` in Mathematica.  I edited this in your post for clarity.  Please check that it's still what you meant to use.

Comment: I don't see the problem. I downloaded it and the following works fine for me: data = Import["test.txt", "Table"];  Please include details on how you import the file... Drop[data,1] to remove headers.

Comment: possible dup http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/2079

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced. Using `Import[table.txt, "Table"]` on your data works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have uploaded your [table.txt](http://hastebin.com/raw/cudesisezu) to a code sharing server. This is exactly like the data should look on your disk.

As already mentioned in several comments, you just have to import it as `"Table"` and everything is fine:

```
data = Import["http://hastebin.com/raw/cudesisezu", "Table"];
data[[2]]

(* {0, 0.997046, -4.00611*10^-6, -0.00442103, 0.299956, 0, -0.00523568,
  0} *)
```

Comment: You're right. The flag "Table" seems to solve the problem. Another way is to use the undocumented mathematica function Internal`StringToDouble[s] as george2079 suggested. Thanks to everyone for your useful comments and answers.