# How to speed up interpreting numbers from strings?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, databaselink, interpreter

In processing a large text file I have batches from `ReadList` of 100,000 `Record`s of the form.

```
SeedRandom[123];
fromReadList = 
  MapThread[
   "1\t2023.203\t" <> #1 <> "\t4.932\t" <> #2 <> "\t" <> #3 <>"\t430.334" &,
   {RandomChoice[{.95, .05} -> {"73.030", "4.3103e+008"}, 100000],
    RandomChoice[{.95, .05} -> {"23.335", "-1.02847e+007"}, 100000],
    RandomChoice[{.4, .4, .2} -> {"Cake", "Cookies", "Muffins"}, 100000]}];
```

There are numbers scattered throughout the file that are in a (scientific) format  that `ToExpression` does not recognize.  Such that when I process the batch like so

```
res = MapThread[#1[#2] &, {Insert[Identity, 6]@ConstantArray[ToExpression, 6], #}] & /@ 
 Select[ContainsAny[{#[[6]]}, {"Cake", "Cookies"}] &]@
  StringSplit[fromReadList]
```

There are entries that are not numbers that should be. (e.g. `res[[2, 3]]` gives `8 + 4.3103 e`).

If `Interpreter["Number"]` is swapped for `ToExpression` then one batch takes far too long to complete considering that the file has 400+ batches to process.

```
MapThread[#1[#2] &, {Insert[Identity, 6]@ConstantArray[Interpreter["Number"], 6], #}] & /@ 
 Select[ContainsAny[{#[[6]]}, {"Cake", "Cookies"}] &]@
  StringSplit[fromReadList]
```

The unrecognized number strings can be in any of the number locations.  How can I either speed up `Interpreter["Number"]` or apply some other technique to process the numbers in the batch.

I am placing the results each batch into a database (`"HSQL(Standalone)"`) using `SQLInsert` and am open to any shortcuts that could take advantage of this.

Comment: Try using ``Internal`StringToDouble`` in place of `ToExpression`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin That works.  How *safe* is it considering that it is in ``Internal` `` and that is undocumented?

Comment: I have a small and primitive LibraryLink based package that can parse numbers in this format or tell you that the input is not a number.  [Here's a usage example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gv6y0.png). Yes, it's clumsy, it's for my own use.  It's very fast though.  If you want, I can make the repo public, but I can't support the package.

Comment: @Leonid The problem with that function is that it won't tell you if the conversion fails.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, that sucks. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Szabolcs It would be nice if you make the repo public - this functionality is often needed.

Comment: @Edmund It is safe in the sense that it is very unlikely that this function will go away. But, there is this problem mentioned by Szabolcs, which is a really bad one.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes. That would be very generous of you to share the repository.

Comment: `Import` and `ImportString` handle the `e` number format okay. `res2 = fromReadList~StringRiffle~"\n"~ImportString~"TSV"~Cases~{__,"Cake"|"Cookies",_};`

Comment: @SimonWoods Please add as an answer. Not only does it import the `e` number format but it is twice as fast as my existing code. (+1)

Comment: Have you tried either of the other two methods I posted in [(1737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/121)?  Particularly ``System`Convert`TableDump`ParseTable`` seemed quite fast the last time I had need of it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had not seen that post. Thanks for sharing. However, @SimonWood post below is the way I think I will go. No undocumented functions and it is twice as fast has my `ToExpression` method above that does not work with the `"e"` format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Import` and `ImportString` handle the e number format okay. You might be able to `Import` directly from file, or use `ImportString` to process the data you've already read in:

```
res = fromReadList ~StringRiffle~ "\n" ~ImportString~ "TSV" ~Cases~ {__,"Cake"|"Cookies",_};
```

Comment: (+1) Its also faster than my initial code.

Comment: To those who found the infix difficult to decipher: `Cases[ImportString[StringRiffle[fromReadList, "\n"], "TSV"], 
  {__, "Cake" | "Cookies", _}]`

Answer (score 14):

I would like to link [this W Community thread here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/869296) where I asked for functionality like this in 2015 September, and explained why it's critical to have it. I can't link to individual posts but you can find it by searching the page for "StringToDouble".

---

As Leonid mentioned, there is `` Internal`StringToDouble ``.  This function is very fast, but it does not report errors.  This makes it unsuitable for applications where not all inputs are numbers, especially when the type of the input is unpredictable.

```
Internal`StringToDouble["1e2"]
(* 100. *)

Internal`StringToDouble["foo"] (* not a number *)
(* 0. *)
```

As a workaround we can make a small LibraryLink function that parses numbers in this format.  Fortunately it's very easy to do in C++.

I am going to use [LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-simplify-writing-librarylink-code/96128#96128) for reasons of laziness (as I always do recently).  LTemplate is absolutely not *needed* here, it just makes it quicker for me to set everything up.

First, put this C++ code in `Parser.h`:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

class Parser {
    bool good;

public:
    double parseReal(const char *s) {
        std::istringstream str(s);
        mma::disownString(s);
        double res;
        str >> res;
        if (str.fail() || ! str.eof()) {
            good = false;
            return 0;
        }
        good = true;
        return res;
    }

    mint parseInteger(const char *s) {
        std::istringstream str(s);
        mma::disownString(s);
        mint res;
        str >> res;
        if (str.fail() || ! str.eof()) {
            good = false;
            return 0;
        }
        good = true;
        return res;
    }

    bool success() const { return good; }
};
```

Then from Mathematica, make sure that `Directory[]` is where `Parser.h` is and evaluate:

```
<<LTemplate`

template = LClass[
  "Parser",
  {
    LFun["parseReal", {"UTF8String"}, Real],
    LFun["parseInteger", {"UTF8String"}, Integer],
    LFun["success", {}, True | False]
  }
];

CompileTemplate[template]
LoadTemplate[template]
```

Then use like this:

[image]

The `parseReal` method parses a real number in `e`-notation.  The `success` method tells us if the parsing was successful.  Then we can build on top of this.

I used this for personal projects.  You can get the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/parser/), but LTemplate must be installed first, and you must also have a working C++ compiler installed... Remember that I made this for personal use.  It's a really basic package and you will probably be better off writing your own, tailed to your own needs.

The only thing this provides over `` Internal`StringToDouble `` is a way to check for errors.

Comment: I didn't realize that it doesn't throw a message on fail and that it needed the extra bits.  Not certain it will work for deploying to Player Pro.  Thanks for sharing. (+1)

Comment: @Edmund I don't have Player Pro, but you're right ... it might not work ... it would also make deployment more complicated because you would need to ship a package which has binaries for all platforms: that means one binary for Windows, one carefully compiled one for Linux to make sure it works on many distros, and two for OS X (for 10.0-10.3 and a different one for 10.4) ...

Comment: Amazing work, this and the LTemplate package. Thank you very much for documenting and sharing.