# Import weird format

Tags: import

I have Spice simulation output file "Sim.txt".
The data within is in a weird non-standard format (the two columns are '\t' separated):

```
Freq.   V(output)
1.00000000000000e+000   (7.99999776894160e+001dB,1.79999988069699e+002°)
1.12201845430196e+000   (7.99999776899954e+001dB,1.79999986613982e+002°)
1.25892541179417e+000   (7.99999776907247e+001dB,1.79999984980640e+002°)
1.41253754462275e+000   (7.99999776916429e+001dB,1.79999983148001e+002°)
1.58489319246111e+000   (7.99999776927988e+001dB,1.79999981091746e+002°)
1.77827941003892e+000   (7.99999776942540e+001dB,1.79999978784591e+002°)
1.99526231496888e+000   (7.99999776960861e+001dB,1.79999976195919e+002°)
2.23872113856834e+000   (7.99999776983925e+001dB,1.79999973291382e+002°)
2.51188643150958e+000   (7.99999777012960e+001dB,1.79999970032438e+002°)
2.81838293126445e+000   (7.99999777049514e+001dB,1.79999966375842e+002°)
...
```

How can I import this data into 3 respective lists?

`Import["Sim.txt","Table"]` imports the first column correctly, but the second and third are imported as one, as text I assume, with parenthesis and units and what not.

Is there a way to `Import` with a defined pattern? Or how would this be done?

Comment: Perhaps a combination of `ReadLine`, `StringSplit`, and `ToExpression`? Are the spaces between the first and second column just spaces, or a tab in the original file? Could you share a sample file (e.g. pastebin, or dropbox link, or similar)?

Comment: The units are volts, decibels, and degrees?

Comment: Yes, those are the units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, J.M.'s comment to one of the answers provided the clues to what is for me the most elegant solution:

```
Import["sim.txt","Table","FieldSeparators" -> {"\t(", "dB,", "°)"}, HeaderLines -> 1];
```

That does it. The data is correctly interpreted (exponentiation and all) into a 3 dimensional list.

The `FieldSeparators` I specify are different than his though. They are the 3 sequences of text that flank the numbers. Even the last "°)" characters are important so the last column is imported in good shape.

Thanks for all of your answers. I learned a lot.

Comment: Good work customizing my suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `input` is a string containing the simulation output, you could do something like this:

```
StringCases[
  Shortest[a__] ~~ Whitespace ~~ "(" ~~ b__ ~~ "dB," ~~ c__ ~~ "°)" :> 
    Internal`StringToDouble /@ {a, b, c}
] /@ Rest@StringSplit[input, "\n"]
```

`StringSplit` breaks the string into lines.  I am assuming that all line terminators are `\n` and not `\r` (pay attention to this).  `Rest` throws away the first line. `StringCases` extracts the three values using string patterns.  All those extra characters such as `(` and `dB` make this easier.

`` Internal`StringToDouble `` is an undocumented function to parse `e`-notation numbers.  Be careful: it doesn't detect incorrect syntax!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it and get a `Dataset`.

```
dat = SemanticImport["Sim.txt", Automatic, "NamedColumns",HeaderLines -> 1];
import[dat_] := Module[{keys, val, sanitize},
   keys = First@StringSplit@Most@Keys@dat;
   val = Values[dat];
   sanitize = (Interpreter["Number"] /@StringSplit[
   (StringReplace[#,{")" -> "", "(" -> "","dB" -> "", "\[Degree]" -> ""}]), ","]) &;
   Transpose@
    Dataset@Association[
      Rule @@@ Transpose@{keys, { First@val, sanitize /@ Last[val]}}]
   ];
import@dat
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do :

```
sample="Freq.   V(output)
1.00000000000000e+000   (7.99999776894160e+001dB,1.79999988069699e+002\[Degree])
1.12201845430196e+000   (7.99999776899954e+001dB,1.79999986613982e+002\[Degree])
1.25892541179417e+000   (7.99999776907247e+001dB,1.79999984980640e+002\[Degree])
1.41253754462275e+000   (7.99999776916429e+001dB,1.79999983148001e+002\[Degree])
1.58489319246111e+000   (7.99999776927988e+001dB,1.79999981091746e+002\[Degree])
1.77827941003892e+000   (7.99999776942540e+001dB,1.79999978784591e+002\[Degree])
1.99526231496888e+000   (7.99999776960861e+001dB,1.79999976195919e+002\[Degree])
2.23872113856834e+000   (7.99999776983925e+001dB,1.79999973291382e+002\[Degree])
2.51188643150958e+000   (7.99999777012960e+001dB,1.79999970032438e+002\[Degree])
2.81838293126445e+000   (7.99999777049514e+001dB,1.79999966375842e+002\[Degree])";
Export["sample.txt",sample,"Text"]  

ReadList["sample.txt",Word,RecordLists->True,WordSeparators->{" ",","}] //
Map[StringReplace[#,{"("-> "",")"-> "","dB"-> "","Â\[Degree]"-> ""}]&,#,{2}]& //
Map[Internal`StringToDouble[#]&,#,{2}]&
```

> {{$Failed["Bad Format"], 0.}, {1., 80., 180.}, {1.12202, 80., 
>     180.}, {1.25893, 80., 180.}, {1.41254, 80., 180.}, {1.58489, 80., 
>     180.}, {1.77828, 80., 180.}, {1.99526, 80., 180.}, {2.23872, 80., 
>     180.}, {2.51189, 80., 180.}, {2.81838, 80., 180.}}

`` Internal`StringToDouble `` is not documented. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1737/5467) . You can instead use `Import[..., "Table"]` but it is very slow.

Comment: `"Table"` could still work: ``Import["Sim.txt", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {"(", ",", " ", ")"}, HeaderLines -> 1] /. x_String :> Internal`StringToDouble[First[StringSplit[x, {"dB", "°"}]]]``. The OP can change to `Quantity[]` objects later if need be.