# Visualize JSON timeseries from Fitbit

Tags: data, json-format

I'm looking to visualize some Fitbit data which comes in json format ([file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/psho5l23j5o0psu/sedentary_minutes.json?dl=1)) . Can someone suggest a nice way to massage this into `DateListPlot`?

```
[{
  "dateTime" : "03/18/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "724"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/19/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "569"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/20/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "594"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/21/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "667"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/22/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "576"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/23/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "532"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/24/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "602"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/25/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "634"
},{
  "dateTime" : "03/26/21 00:00:00",
  "value" : "632"
}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON dataset is imported as a list of rules:

```
{
  {"dateTime" -> "07/07/14 00:00:00", "value" -> "1440"}, 
  {"dateTime" -> "07/08/14 00:00:00", "value" -> "1128"}, ...
}
```

So take the second part of each Rule for each point to give string pairs. Then use `DateObject` with an appropriate template on the first string of the pair to obtain a date, and `ToExpression` on the second string to obtain a number. Then feed to `DateListPlot`.

```
data = Import["sedentary_minutes.json"][[All, All, 2]];

formatted = 
  {
    DateObject[{#1, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "YearShort", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}], 
    ToExpression[#2]
  }& @@@ data;

DateListPlot[formatted]
```

[image: result of DateListPlot]

---

A more performant alternative might be to avoid `DateObject` and `ToExpression`.

1. Since the data appears regularly spaced with one minute intervals, one can use the `datespec` argument to `DateListPlot` to specify a start date and a granularity, with an end date automatically calculated from the number of data points present.
2. A faster alternative to `ToExpression` is [`` Internal`StringToDouble ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/27951).

Combining the two, but only showing four points a day, i.e. every six hours rather than every minute:

```
data = Import["calories.json"][[All, All, 2]];
values = Internal`StringToDouble /@ data[[All, 2]];

DateListPlot[
  values[[;; ;; 360]], 
  {{2014, 07, 07, 0, 0, 0}, Automatic, {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0}},
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Consider that including more points won't lead to much more information being conveyed by your plot: choosing to include only four points a day already results in close to 10,000 points being plotted. You would need an extremely high resolution medium to distinguish more than those.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Mostly worked but didn't scale to a larger dataset (200M json for calories burned https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbh9jteggqreko9/calories.json?dl=1), wondering if the issue is the many DateTime objects being constructed

Comment: @Yaroslal Take a look at the alternative approach that avoid DateObject and ToExpression. That should be quite a bit faster.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks!