# Flipping axis on a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to make a 2D plot where the x-axis is flipped so the higher numbers are on the right and lower numbers are on the left.

I've managed to do it by flipping the data and making new `Ticks` but this solution is manually and requires manipulating the data. I was hoping there was a better way.

For the normal plot:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 20, 100}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And for the flipped data and the new plot:

```
data = Table[{100 - x + 20, x^2}, {x, 20, 100}];
ticks = Table[{x, 100 - x + 20}, {x, 20, 100, 10}]
ListLinePlot[data, Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I couldn't seem to find any options like `ReverseAxis`.

Comment: You've flipped the curve (and that is easily done indeed), but I don't see any difference in the ticks between your first and second image... are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: @J.M. fixed, thanks.

Comment: related http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/e3f356f8028208d1/d2385a2984b8c26b?lnk=gst&q=inverting+axis&rnum=10&pli=1

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5655224/618728

Answer (score 45, accepted):

@Mr. Wizard pointed to a thread that mentioned the option `ScalingFunctions` which works for `BarChart` and `Histogram` according to the documentation and supports a `Reverse` option.

I simply tried this with `ListLinePlot` and although the `ScalingFunctions` appears in red, it works!

```
ListLinePlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thanks @Mr. Wizard and undocumented magic functions!

Comment: It is of note that this does not work in version 7.  Good find for v8 users!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with `DateListPlot`, but it does work with `ListPlot`/`ListLinePlot`. As well as `"Reverse"`, `"Log"` and `"Log10"` seem to work.

Comment: Good find! Sometimes you just have to outsmart the manual.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Does this work in version 9?

Comment: This method seems to be very nice. However, if plot with frame, the frame ticks would then be exactly "reversed". For example here the ticks would range from -100 to -20. Any way to improve it?

Comment: This solution prevents graphics primitives from rendering using `Epilog` (using 10.4).

Comment: lifesaver! thanks! still works in 11.3

Answer (score 16):

Here is a bit different solution

```
d = Transpose@data;
ListLinePlot[ Transpose@{Reverse@d[[1]], d[[2]]}, 
              Ticks -> {Transpose@{Range[20, 100, 10], Range[100, 20, -10]}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

If we don't like to specify in advance ranges of ticks, here is another, more general approach :

```
ListLinePlot[ Transpose @ { Reverse@ d[[1]], d[[2]]}, 
              Ticks -> {Transpose @ { Range[ Min[#], Max[#], 
                                     10^(Ceiling@Log[10, (Max[#] - Min[#])] - 1)] &@d[[1]], 
                                     Range[Max[#], Min[#], 
                                     -10^(Ceiling@Log[10, (Max[#] - Min[#])] - 1)] & @ d[[1]]},
                                      Automatic}]
```

Comment: @belisarius I was mislead by two different definitions of `data` in the OP question. So I had to update my earlier answer.

Comment: I imagined that, and posted my comment so that you could come with a different answer. Well done +1

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for an upvote. I don't understand your approach. The plot in your post seems to be ok, but when I applied your solution to the first definition of `data` in the OP question  the ticks on the `x` axes are not reversed. How do I get what the OP wanted ?

Comment: Something got tangled (probably some neurons) when I pasted the code here. Thanks for the warning! Try the code now

Comment: @belisarius Now it works  +1.

Answer (score 9):

For flipping the axes I use the following function:

```
Options[flippeAchsen] = Union[{Achsen -> 1}, Options[Graphics]];
flippeAchsen[pp_Graphics, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{tx, ty, labx, laby, GAPx, GAPy, qq, xyRule, x, y, achs, 
   TICKS, ticks, gropts, frame, FTall}, achs = OptionValue[Achsen];
  If[achs > 3, FTall = True; achs = Mod[achs, 3, 1], FTall = False];
  frame = OptionValue[Frame];
  TICKS = If[frame === True, FrameTicks, Ticks];
  gropts = Sequence @@ FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], Options[Graphics]];
  tx = AbsoluteOptions[pp, TICKS][[1, 2, 1]];
  ty = AbsoluteOptions[pp, TICKS][[1, 2, 2]];
  labx = Select[Flatten[Cases[tx, {n_, l_, rest__}]], NumericQ];
  laby = Select[Flatten[Cases[ty, {n_, l_, rest__}]], NumericQ];
  GAPx = Max[labx] - Min[labx];
  GAPy = Max[laby] - Min[laby];
  Which[achs == 1,(*x Achse*)
   xyRule = {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> {GAPx - x, y};
   ticks = {Map[{GAPx - First[#], Sequence @@ Rest[#]} &, tx], ty}, 
   achs == 2,(*y Achse*)
   xyRule = {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> {x, GAPy - y};
   ticks = {tx, Map[{GAPy - First[#], Sequence @@ Rest[#]} &, ty]}, 
   achs == 3,(*beide Achsen*)
   xyRule = {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> {GAPx - x, GAPy - y};
   ticks = {Map[{GAPx - First[#], Sequence @@ Rest[#]} &, tx], 
     Map[{GAPy - First[#], Sequence @@ Rest[#]} &, ty]}];
  ticks = 
   If[frame === True, 
    If[FTall === 
      True, {{ticks[[2]], ticks[[2]]}, {ticks[[1]], 
       ticks[[1]]}}, {{ticks[[2]], None}, {ticks[[1]], None}}], ticks];
  Show[pp /. xyRule, Evaluate[gropts], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All,
    AxesOrigin -> AbsoluteOptions[pp, AxesOrigin][[1, 2]] /. xyRule, 
   TICKS -> ticks]]
```

The option Achsen choses the axes to flip:

`Achsen->1` reverts the first (x-axis)
`Achsen->2` reverts the second (y-axis
`Achsen->3` reverts both

If you use `FrameTicks` you must pass this option to `flippeAchsen` too.
In frames the ticks are drawn bottom and left by default. If one want the Ticks on all four sides, just add 3 to the option `Achsen`.

Call is: `flippeAchsen[plot, Achsen->number]`

Comment: Thanks it works, however, when I run `flippeAchsen[ListLinePlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {100, 0}], Achsen -> 1]` I get a few errors `OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option Achsen for flippeAchsen. >>`

Comment: @s0rce For me it works. Did you copy the first Line of the code `Options[flippeAchsen]=Union...` ?

Comment: nope, I missed it. Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 9):

Mike Honeychurch wrote a package [`ReverseListPlot`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7525/) that does this; it's available on *MathSource*.

Answer (score 4):

Probably can be simplified:

```
k1 = Transpose@({Reverse[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &@Transpose@data);
ListLinePlot[k1, 
 Ticks -> ({Transpose[({#[[1]], Reverse@#[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]} &@
           Transpose[Sort@#[[1, 2, 1]]])], #[[1, 2, 2]]} &@
                                                    AbsoluteOptions[ListLinePlot@k1, Ticks])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following commands:

```
g = Plot[x^2, {x, 20, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[g /. x_Line :> Reverse[x, 3], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't show the same output as the other answers.

Comment: The question is about flipping the y-axis values, not exchanging them with the x-axis.