# Manipulating the axis on a ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a plot using `ListLinePlot` in which the x-axis is represented in a logarithmic scale, and is reversed (so larger values are on the right side).

I have found that `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse"}` will reverse the axis and `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}` will scale the axis to a log scale, but the two commands will not work together.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In *Mathematica* 8, ScalingFunctions is not an option for `ListLinePlot`. Are you using a different version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: @CarlMorris actually, they are not documented to do so, [but they do](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/8) ([see also here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5718/8)).

Comment: @Verbeia It seems "Reverse" does not work for `ListLogLinearPlot`

Comment: @Verde I know, but I got tangled in my answer and hadn't posted it until now.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to stick with `ScalingFunctions` then you just have to use a pure function where you specify the transformation you would like to have. Simple example:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, x^2 + 10}, {x, 0, 10, 1}],
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, {Sqrt[# - 10] &, #^2 + 10 &}}
]
```

So what you have to do is to supply a function for the x-axis which reverses and takes the log and you need to supply the inverse transformation for that.

Comment: Take a look at this : `#[Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 1000}], 
   ScalingFunctions -> {{-Log@# &, E^-# &}, None}] & /@ {ListPlot, 
  ListLinePlot}`

Answer (score 8):

```
tick = AbsoluteOptions[ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 1000}]], Ticks][[1,2]];
t1 = {tick[[1]] /. {x_, y_, z_, w_} -> {-x, y, z, w}, tick[[2]]};
ListPlot[Table[{-Log@n, Sqrt[n]}, {n, 1000}], Ticks -> t1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(*The usual credit to @Heike for her `torn[]` function*)

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a way you can get *both* log and reversed x-axes out of the box.

Consider some data that might warrant such a presentation:

```
data = Sort@RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[0.2, 2.], {40, 2}];
```

`ListLogLinearPlot` gives a log x-axis and normal y-axis

```
ListLogLinearPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The `ScalingFunction` option isn't meant to work for `ListLinePlot`, but it actually does.

```
ListLinePlot[data, Joined -> True, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}]
```

[image]

However, it doesn't work for `ListLogLinearPlot`.

So, the answer is to manipulate data and ticks much in the same way as Verde's answer suggests.

You can write a custom tick function that takes the maximum and minimum data points and builds tick functions from that. I am not going to pretend this is quite the function you want (I got tangled and don't have time to fix it now), but you can see how to build a general tick function that doesn't require specific knowledge of the data upfront.

```
 loggedticks[min_, max_] :=
   Table[{i, ScientificForm[10^i]}, {i, Floor@Log[10, min],Ceiling@Log[10, max]}] 

ListLogLinearPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
  Ticks -> {loggedticks, Automatic}]
```

Comment: There _is_ a way to get both things with ScalingFunctions. See halirutan's answer and my comment below. Really unexpected.