# reversing plot axis for Plot, LogPlot, LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting

Is there a simple way to reverse axis on a plot (all --- [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) and [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html)and [`LogLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html)). I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot) but it deals with [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html). Also I tried [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) but they make put the origin wrongly. Also it does not seem to work for logarithmic plots.

What I want is the same plot but x-axis starting from `λL` and ending in `λH` with the origin on the left hand side of the plot. Also I am not sure if some tick rewriting will work as suggested in some other solutions as I really need to start from the left with the plot not just the ticks.

```
h = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"], "SIBase"]];
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "SIBase"]];
kB = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"], "SIBase"]];

TSun = 5800;(* Kelvins *)
TEarth = 255;(* Kelvins *)
Bλ[T_, λ_] := (2 h*c^2)/λ^5 1/(Exp[h/(kB*T) c/λ] - 1);

λL = 1*10^-9;(* "Meters" *)
λH = 100*10^-6;(* "Meters" *)

Plot[{Bλ[TSun, λ], 10^6*Bλ[TEarth, λ]}, {λ, λH, λL}, 
  PlotLegends -> {
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Sun\)]\) = 5800 K", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Earth\)]\) = 255 K"}, 
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Related questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3747/3066 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84496/3066

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but ScalingFunctions does nothing on LogLogPlot. Also its results on Plot are not what I would expect (they just seem wrong).

Answer (score 6):

You want to reverse the plotting range `{1.*10^-9, 0.0001}` to `{0.0001, 1.*10^-9}` but *Mathematica* always wants to plot the variable with the smallest value on the left.  So make a function that linearly reverses the scale between the two:

```
f[x_] := -x + λH + λL;
f /@ {1.`*^-9, 0.0001`}
(* {0.0001, 1.*10^-9} *)
```

Now when you plot the functions they are reversed

```
Plot[{Bλ[TSun, f[λ]], 
  10^6*Bλ[TEarth, 
    f[λ]]}, {λ, λL, λH}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now you have to deal with the tick marks.  You can change them manually, or you can give a pure function `Function[{min,max},.....]` but both of these are too much trouble for me.  I just take advantage of the fantastic [`CustomTicks`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package.  In this case, we just need to feed the mapping function to the option `TickPostTransformation`

```
Plot[{Bλ[TSun, f[λ]], 
  10^6*Bλ[TEarth, 
    f[λ]]}, {λ, λL, λH},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Ticks -> {LinTicks[λH, λL,
    TickPostTransformation -> f],
   Automatic}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Sun\)]\) = 5800 K", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Earth\)]\) = 255 K"}]
```

[image]

This works great for `LogPlot` as well, although you need to disable `PlotRange->All` as the y-axis would go to very large negative values.

```
{LogPlot[{Bλ[TSun, λ], 
   10^6*Bλ[
     TEarth, λ]}, {λ, λL, λH}], 
 LogPlot[{Bλ[TSun, f[λ]], 
   10^6*Bλ[TEarth, 
     f[λ]]}, {λ, λL, λH},
  Ticks -> {LinTicks[λH, λL,
     TickPostTransformation -> f],
    Automatic}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Sun\)]\) = 5800 K", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Earth\)]\) = 255 K"}]}
```

[image]

As for a `LogLogPlot`, I found the easiest way to do it was to make a `LogPlot` and scale the x-axes manually.  I've also set the plotrange manually to avoid the [problem you also encountered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107373/9490)

```
f2[x_] := -x + Log10@λL + Log10@λH;
{LogLogPlot[{Bλ[TSun, λ], 
   10^6*Bλ[TEarth, λ]},
  {λ, λL, λH},
  PlotRange -> {1, Automatic}],
 LogPlot[{Bλ[TSun, 10^f2[λ]], 
   10^6*Bλ[TEarth, 10^f2[λ]]},
  {λ, Log10@λL, Log10@λH},
  PlotRange -> {1, Automatic},
  Ticks -> {LogTicks[Log10@λL, Log10@λH,
     TickPostTransformation -> f2],
    Automatic},
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Sun\)]\) = 5800 K", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Earth\)]\) = 255 K"}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This also works.

```
ParametricPlot[{{ λ, Bλ[TSun, λ]}, { λ, 10^6*Bλ[TEarth, λ]}}, {λ, λH, λL}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[ {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Sun\)]\) = 5800 K", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(Earth\)]\) = 255 K"}, Left], 
    PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}]
```

[image]

It is based on Mr. Wizard's answer to question [13253](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13255/1063).

**Addendum**

For a Log plot, use (for example)

```
ParametricPlot[{x, Exp[x]}, {x, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Log"}]
```

[image]

and for a Log-Log plot,

```
ParametricPlot[{x, Exp[x]}, {x, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {{-Log10[#] &, (10^-#) &}, "Log"}]
```

[image]