# Plotting Planck's function and unexpected results

Tags: plotting, numerics

I have the code below. If you look at the plot, you can see a strange behaviour. The function goes to zero as `λ->0` but you can see the plateau below approximately 5e-8. Yet, if I evaluate the function at 1e-8 I get basically zero. What is the source of this behaviour?

[image]

```
ch = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"], "SIBase"]];
cc = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "SIBase"]];
ckB = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"], "SIBase"]];
TSun = 5800;(* Kelvins *)
TEarth = 255;(* Kelvins *)

Bλ[T_, λ_] := (2 ch*cc^2)/λ^5 1/(Exp[ch/(ckB*T) cc/λ] - 1);

λH = 1000*10^-6;(* "Meters" *)
λL = 10.0*10^-9;(* "Meters" *)

LogLogPlot[Bλ[TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH}, Frame -> True]

Bλ[TEarth, 1.0*10^-8]
```

Comment: The workaround of choosing the properly scaled units here (e.g. nanometers) should alleviate this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because $10^{-2427}$ is beyond the `$MinMachineNumber`, $2.2250738585072014 \times 10^{-308}$.

```
LogLogPlot[
 Bλ[TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can call this a bug, but it seems buggy to me.  Let's take a look at the data that is actually being plotted, which you can extract using a `Reap` and `Sow` combination (thanks to @user21 for showing me this trick)

```
Reap[LogLogPlot[Sow[{λ, Bλ[TEarth, λ]}]; 
     Bλ[TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH}, 
     Frame -> True]][[2, 1, ;; 20]] // TableForm
```

[image]

That would **seem** to be the big glaring problem, right there, that point of `{x,f[x]} = {-18.4207,  1.83338*10^-17}`.  But I'm not actually convinced, I think that is a red herring, because you get the same x value if you replace `Bλ[TEarth, λ]` with `λ^2`.

About the only thing we do learn from that table is that *Mathematica* doesn't seem to have a problem with **really** small numbers.

This is apparently one of those cases where you need to use `Evaluate` in the argument to `Plot`,

```
GraphicsRow[{
  LogLogPlot[
   Bλ[TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH},
    Frame -> True],
  LogLogPlot[
   Evaluate@
    Bλ[
     TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH}, 
   Frame -> True]
  }, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

This is a simple workaround that you can use all the time without drawback.

### Working Precision giving crazy results

It was suggested to check out the results of using `WorkingPrecision` on the plot, so look at this mess:

```
LogLogPlot[
   Bλ[TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH},
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> #, 
   ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {MachinePrecision/2, MachinePrecision, 
  2 MachinePrecision, $MachinePrecision}
```

[image]

The only setting that was even close to correct was the default setting.  It seems the only real answer here is to wrap the function with `Evaluate` before plotting.

**Edit**  Here is my original answer below, which I'm leaving in only because it shows off the version 10 function [`PlanckRadiationLaw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanckRadiationLaw.html), which is a little slow for sure.

@J.M. made the point of using nanometers instead of meters, and my first thought was to use atomic units instead of SI units, but you still run into the same problem when taking a `LogLog` plot.

Your code is just fine, but I thought I'd show off a version 10 function here,

```
LogLogPlot[{
  QuantityMagnitude[
   PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[5778, "Kelvins"], 
    Quantity[x, "Nanometers"]]],
  QuantityMagnitude[
   PlanckRadiationLaw[Quantity[255, "Kelvins"], 
    Quantity[x, "Nanometers"]]]}
 , {x, 10, 10^6}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Quantity[None, "Nanometers"], 
   Quantity[None, "Watts"/("Hertz"*"Meters"^2*"Steradians")]}]
```

[image]

shows the same problem, even with proper units.  But if you adjust the lowest wavelength to 100 nm, then you get this:

[image]

Comment: I understand how to correct it, I am more curious why the behaviour is like this, ie. why Mathematica shows this apparently wrong limit for the function? Also, notice that Mathematica does not issue any warning that the number is too small and it is confusing, I think there can be more complicated functions where the result is not so apparently wrong and you can produce nonsense without noticing it. Also, I am curious, why this really happens, is the issue with comparing the numbers that are beyond the `$MinMachineNumber` or is it some type of overflow?

Comment: @leosenko - you may have to write to the developers to get a good answer.  You can rephrase the question to leave out the extraneous stuff, like the units and planck's constant.  You can just define a function as `f[x_] := 10^-16 x^-5/(Exp[5 10^-5/x]);` and then compare the results of `LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 10^-8, 10^-3}]` to `LogLogPlot[10^-16 x^-5/(Exp[5 10^-5/x]), {x, 10^-8, 10^-3}]`  That would make it a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Changing the setting of `WorkingPrecision` is also useful: `LogLogPlot[Bλ[TEarth, λ], {λ, λL, λH}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]`.

Comment: @J.M. - That's crazy, just makes me even more confused.  See the edit