# How to reverse values of x along x-axis

Tags: plotting

I have the following function to plot

```
F[x_] := 0.00150614 Sqrt[1/x]
```

I know *Mathematica* plots in a format

```
Plot[F[x], {xmin, xmax}]
```

but I would like to plot the other way around:

```
Plot[F[x], {xmax, xmin}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Normally `{x, upperLimit, lowerLimit}` also works... But the plot is the same...

Comment: ave you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107370/reversing-plot-axis-for-plot-logplot-loglogplot)?

Comment: I am trying to visualize the propagation of electromagnetic wave towards the conical tip along z-axis. As I proceed toward the tip my radius decreases. So R[z]. I want as z->0, R->0 and not z->0, R->Ro which is when you take the origin at the base of the cone. So all I need plotting my function from z-max to 0.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{x - 10, F[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]` ?

Answer (score 5):

There is a way with `ListPlot`. You can always generate a list with your function and use with `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`.

```
F[x_] := 0.00150614 Sqrt[1/x]
xmin = 0.01; xmax = 1.0;
data = {#, F[#]} & /@ Range[xmin, xmax, 0.01];
ListLinePlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, AxesOrigin -> {xmax, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing is to "reverse" the argument to f. For instance, here is f plotted forwards and backwards:

```
f[x_] := 0.00150614 Sqrt[1/x];
xmin = 0.25; xmax = 3;
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}],
 Plot[f[xmax + xmin - x], {x, xmin, xmax}]]
```

[image]