# Show linear plot as log plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have a `listplot` and `plot` of fit functions which I combine with `Show[listplot, plot]`. However I also need to show the same plot with logarithmic axes. A proper way of doing this is avoiding any duplication of code, so that any changes on the legend, line style etc. always appears on both plots and doesn't need to be copied. How can this be done?

To make it more clear, my code looks like this:

```
 listplot=ListPlot[{data1, data2}, options1, option2, ...]
 plot=Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], ...}, {x,a,b}, options3, option4, ...]
 Show[listplot, plot]
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by avoiding the duplication of the code but how about `LogLogPlot`, `ListLogLogPlot`, they have the same options as `Plot` and `ListPlot` so you can assign the options beforehand and use the assignment. You can also set the options inside `Show`, however, I am not sure that this can contain all the options that are available for the `Plot`.

Comment: you can use `ScalingFunctions`. Chek this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112768/8070)

Comment: @leosenko and Sumit I have made my question more explicit, but still don't know how to apply your suggestions without duplicating part of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, using a replacement rule to replace every `y` value with a scaled version, and then making sure that you have a scaled tick mark function as well

```
plot = Plot[{x^x, Exp[x], x!}, {x, 1, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
Show[plot /. Line[x__] :> (({#1, Log@#2} & @@@ x) // Line),
 PlotRange -> All,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, with OP's example more explicitly

```
listplot = 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{#^#, Exp[#], #!} & /@ Range[1, 5]], 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker@Blue, Darker@Red, Darker@Green}];
plot = Plot[{x^x, Exp[x], x!}, {x, 1, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, PlotRange -> All];
combined = Show[plot, listplot]
Show[combined /.
  {Line[x__] :> (({#1, Log@#2} & @@@ x) // Line), 
   Point[x__] :> (({#1, Log@#2} & @@@ x) // Point)},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Any docs on ``Charting`ScaledTicks``?

Comment: It's one of those hidden functions I learned about from this site, like ``Charting`get2DPlotRange``.  I had to google it to find the example on here to follow.  I do know it doesn't work as well on `FrameTicks`

Comment: @BlacKow It **seems** like it should take two pure functions that are the inverse of each other, and scale accordingly, but I remember trying to do a simple example on a density plot with `#^3` and `#^(1/3)` and not being able to get it to work.  But it works for generating log ticks. Anything more complicated and I use the CustomTicks package's `TickPreTransformation` and `TickPostTransformation` functions

Comment: I see... I was wondering why you need `Exp` **and** `Log`... Thank you!

Comment: I tried `Normal[plot] /. Line[x__] :> x` to extract the coordinates of the `plot`, it failed. Did you know why? Other right trials I have done are `Cases[plot, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity]` or `Reap@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin[x]}]]`. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you already have this `Plot`.

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x]
f2[x_] := Cos[x]
plot1 = Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Now I am only going to change the scaling. I use a linear scaling. You can use `Log` as well

```
newplot[plot_, xmin_, xmax_, ymin_, ymax_] := Module[{fx, fy, q},
   fx[q_] := q/2;
   fy[q_] := 1.5 q;
   plot /. {Line[z__] :> Line[z /. {x_, y_} :> {fx[x], fy[y]}], 
   (PlotRange -> z__) :> PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}}]
```

You must define new `PlotRange` as `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax`, otherwise the plot may not look good. And Now we apply it on our existing `plot`

```
newplot[plot1, 0, 4, -1.5, 1.5]
```

[image]

New scaling with old options. If you want to convert the `x` values with their `Log` use `fx[q_]:=Log[q]` and likewise..