# Problem when trying to reverse function

Tags: parametric-functions, convolution

A minimal example is below. I'm trying to reverse function *y1d*.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] (* clear all symbols *)
f0d = 3.5*10^9;
f1d = 500*10^6;
T = 0.1*10^-6;
kd = (f1d - f0d)/T;
phi0 = 0;
chplusd[t_] := E^(I*2*\[Pi]*((kd*t^2)/2 + f0d*t + phi0))
fsig1 = 3*10^9;
x[t_] := Cos[2*Pi*fsig1*t]
s1d[t_] := x[t]*chplusd[t]
snd[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*(f0d*t + phi0))
y2d[t_] := s1d[t]*snd[t]
Grid[{{Plot[{Re[y2d[t]]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}, {Plot[{Re[y2d[T - t]]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}}]
chmoinsd[t_] := E^(-I*2*\[Pi]*((kd*t^2)/2 + f0d*t + phi0))
y1dtemp = Convolve[y2d[to]*UnitStep[to], chmoinsd[to]*UnitStep[to], to, t, Assumptions -> t >= 0]
y1d[t_] := y1dtemp
Grid[{{Plot[{Re[y1d[t]]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}, {Plot[{Re[y1d[T - t]]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}}]
```

The problem starts in the line with the *Convolve* function, because I can reverse function *y2d*.

Before, I tried the below two lines in place of the last three lines of the above code, but it does not work and I don't understand why.

```
y1d[t_] := Convolve[y2d[to]*UnitStep[to], chmoinsd[to]*UnitStep[to], to, t, Assumptions -> t >= 0]
Grid[{{Plot[{Re[y1d[t]]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}, {Plot[{Re[y1d[T - t]]}, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}}]
```

Comment: The code runs without any error messages and there is no obvious indication of what problem you are referring to. Could you please be more explicit about what is "the problem" and what you mean by "reverse a function"? Do you mean to find the inverse function?

Comment: The code block runs without problems, but if you change the last three lines of the code block by the two lines I've given below the code block, Mathematica is unable to plot _y1d_, processing never ends. By "reversing a function", I mean create a function _g[t]_ of the form: g[0]=f[T], f[0+dt]=f[T-dt], ... , g[T]=f[0], like what was made by _Bill S_, in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112696/how-to-reverse-values-of-x-along-x-axis

Comment: In the example given, I reversed _y2d_. You can see in the plot. But _y1d_ is not reversed, the plots are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example you asking Mathematica to evaluate the expression  at every point.

This is a lot of extra work (it will eventually complete I think).

Instead wrap the expression in `Evaluate` so the closed form (i.e., equivalent to `y1dtemp` is used to make the plot.

Note: not part of the question but you don't need the curly brackets around the expression.

```
Grid[{
    {Plot[Evaluate[Re[y1d[t]]], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> Full]},
     {Plot[Evaluate[Re[y1d[T - t]]], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All,
     Exclusions -> None, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> Full]}
    }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]