# How does the undocumented option ScalingFunctions work with Plot versus ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, ticks

Say that I want to reverse the x-axis of a plot, there are a few solutions on here (like those in the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3747/9490) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84498/9490)) but most of them are valid only for a `ListPlot` variant and not a `Plot` variant.

The answer by MarcoB in the second link above uses the option `ScalingFunctions` to achieve the goal and I was interested in how to apply it to a `Plot` (or `LogPlot` or `LogLogPlot`, etc).  It seems to work just fine in reversing the x-axis if the function being plotted is linear:

```
{Plot[2 (k - 2), {k, -5, 0}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[2 (k - 2), {k, -5, 0}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{-# &, -# &}, Identity}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image]

but it gives strange results when the function is nonlinear,

```
{Plot[2 (k - 2)^3, {k, -5, 0}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[2 (k - 2)^3, {k, -5, 0}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{-# &, -# &}, Identity}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image]

If I try the same thing on a `ListPlot` it works just fine,

```
list = {#, 2 (# - 2)^3} & /@ Range[-5, 0, .1];
{ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[list, ScalingFunctions -> {{-# &, -# &}, Identity},
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this with `ScalingFunctions`, or is it simply not supported and I need to use [my own workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107391/9490)?

Comment: Even simpler problematic case: `Plot[0, {t, 0, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Log"}]` puts the line at `y == 1` when there should be no line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examination of the two nonlinear `Plot`s (from the second piece of code in the question) with `InputForm` shows that `ScalingFunctions` correctly modifies the `Ticks` option but retains only the first and last elements of `Line` .  Based on this observation, a fairly simple work-around is

(Edit: code simplified)

```
Plot[2 (k - 2)^3, {k, -5, 0}, PlotRange -> All] /. 
    {Line[z_] :> Line[MapAt[-# &, z, {All, 1}]], 
     Rule[Ticks, {_, z_}] -> Rule[Ticks, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{-#1 &, -#1 &}], z}]}
```

[image]

**Addendum**

`ScalingFunctions` works fine with `ParametricPlot`, although apparently not with `Plot`.  Thus,

```
ParametricPlot[{k, 2 (k - 2)^3}, {k, -5, 0}, ScalingFunctions -> {{-# &, -# &}, Identity}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

also produces the plot above.  This update is based on Mr. Wizard's answer to question [13253](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13255/1063).  Incidentally, `"Reverse"` has the same effect as `{-# &, -# &}`.

**Problem resolved for version 12.1, perhaps earlier.**

With "12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)", the problem described in the question no longer exists.

Comment: I particularly like the idea of using `ParametricPlot` as a stand-in for `Plot` when rescaling is needed, since it enjoys similar adaptive sampling etc. Very clever workaround! (+1)

Comment: I agree, brilliant to use `ParametricPlot`!  Especially since I am continually confunded by `Charting\`ScaledTicks`, and always resort to `CustomTicks` instead.

Comment: @JasonB  Thank you for your acceptance and kind words.  Do you feel that the behavior of `Charting`ScaledTicks` in `Plot` is a bug?  Although it is not documented, this option is recognized by `Plot` and produces an incorrect answer.  Also, according to the documentation of `Plot` and `ParametricPlot`, the former is a special case of the latter.