# Flipping x-tick-labels on custom plot

Tags: graphics

I'm slightly new to the world of Mathematica, so I can't assess the difficulty of my request, but anyhow, this is my question:

I have 2 datasets that I want to plot with two y axes, and a reversed x axis.
(as to 'why do you want a reversed x-axis': the time parameter is in thousand years before present, which decreases in value as time moves forward, such that 0 is the present day)

The data is the following:

```
area = {{0, 443.387}, {1, 443.387}, {2, 443.387}, {3, 443.387}, {4, 
 443.387}, {5, 444.06}, {6, 445.406}, {7, 446.751}, {8, 447.424}, {9,
 698.385}, {10, 718.57}, {11, 734.044}, {12, 772.395}, {13, 
 822.856}, {14, 878.7}, {15, 5933.58}, {16, 6837.85}, {17, 
 7254.32}, {18, 7362.65}, {19, 7458.86}, {20, 7540.94}, {21, 
 7621.01}}                    ;
distance = {{0, 10.3807}, {1, 10.3807}, {2, 10.3807}, {3, 10.3807}, {4, 
 10.0923}, {5, 10.0923}, {6, 10.0923}, {7, 10.0923}, {8, 
 10.0923}, {9, 9.69003}, {10, 9.65897}, {11, 9.65897}, {12, 
 9.35579}, {13, 8.94344}, {14, 8.22982}, {15, 7.4932}, {16, 
 6.66484}, {17, 5.21611}, {18, 5.21611}, {19, 4.47083}, {20, 
 3.94395}, {21, 3.72562}}     ;
```

I made a  YY-plot code using this code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/647/11219, which produces:

[image: YY_plot-example]

And then reversed the original data using the code as found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5717/11219, which should reverse both the data and the axis ticks.

[image]

As I hope you can see: the data is transformed correctly, the labels on the x-axis are not. So in combining the two codes I found, I broke the Ticks on the x-axis. Is it possible to fix this? Even a manual setting of the labels is fine with me, all my plots have the same data range from 21--0. The current code is:

```
TwoAxisListLinePlot[{f_, g_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    ListLinePlot[#, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]], 
      Mesh -> Full,
      Ticks -> ({Transpose[({#[[1]], 
                Reverse@#[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]} &@
              Transpose[Sort@#[[1, 2, 1]]])], #[[1, 2, 2]]} &@
         AbsoluteOptions[ListLinePlot@#1, Ticks])
      ] &, {f, g}]; {frange, grange} = 
   Last[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph};
  fticks = 
   Last[Ticks /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[fgraph, 
       Ticks]] /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue :> ColorData[1][1];
  gticks = (MapAt[Function[r, Rescale[r, grange, frange]], #, {1}] & /@
       Last[Ticks /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[ggraph, 
         Ticks]]) /. _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue -> ColorData[1][2];
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Years before present [ka]", "Area [km\.b2]", "", 
     "Isolation [km]"},
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

And then run as

```
k1 = Transpose@({Reverse[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &@Transpose@area);
k2 = Transpose@({Reverse[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &@Transpose@distance);
TwoAxisListLinePlot[{k1, k2}]
```

Comment: *"Even a manual setting of the labels is fine with me, all my plots have the same data range from 21--0."* -- Well, what have you tried?  Look at the documentation for `Ticks` and `FrameTicks`.  I'll be glad to help if you get stuck.

Comment: It seems that ScalingFunctions is partially fixed in V9. I can't reproduce [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5718/5478) behaviour.

Comment: I used the method in Kuba's answer below to set the ticks to:
"FrameTicks -> {{fticks, 
     gticks}, {{#, If[Mod[#, 5] == 1, 21 - #, ""], 
        If[Mod[#, 5] == 1, {0.009, 0}, {0.005, 0}]} & /@ 
      Range[0, 21, 
       1], {#, "", If[Mod[#, 5] == 1, {0.01, 0}, {0.005, 0}]} & /@ 
      Range[0, 21, 1]}}]]" ---

Which did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With[{opt = {ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> Thick}},
 Overlay[{
   ListLinePlot[Reverse@area[[ ;; , 2]], Frame -> {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, opt, PlotStyle -> Red,
                                         FrameStyle -> Red,  DataRange -> {0, 21}],
   ListLinePlot[Reverse@distance[[ ;; , 2]], opt, Frame -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
                                             FrameStyle -> Blue, PlotStyle -> Blue,
                                             DataRange -> {0, 21}, 
                                             FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}], 
   Plot[, {x, 0, 21}, opt, Axes -> False, Frame -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
        FrameTicks -> {{None, All},
                      {{#, If[OddQ[#], 21 - #, ""]} & /@ Range[0, 21, 1/2], None}}
       ]      
   }]]
```

[image]