# flipping y axis

Tags: plotting, data

I know that some topics were created for this subject but any solution works for me.
I would like to reverse the y axis. By this I mean that I would like to have the highest values at the bottom and the lowest at the top.

Here is a minimal example:
`x = Table[Log[10, minimal[[i, 2]]], {i, 1, Length[minimal]}]
y = Table[minimal[[i, 11]], {i, 1, Length[minimal]}]
error = Table[Log[10, minimal[[i, 3]]], {i, 1, Length[minimal]}]`
giving:
{0.959041, 1.0406, 0.590188, 0.576065}
{-19.7381, -12.479, -18.8248, -17.4789}
{1.01921, 0.385606, 0.737037, -0.146194}

The third list is the errors corresponding to the values in the first list.
I use now ErrorListPlot:

```
minimalplot = ErrorListPlot[Table[{{x[[i]], y[[i]]}, ErrorBar[error[[i]]]}, {i, 1, 
Length[minimal]}], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

And I get this:
[image]
The problem is that the highest y value (-12.479) is at the top of the y axis by default and the lowest (-19.7381) is at the bottom.

I know that ScalingFunctions work with Plot and ListPlot but it doesn't work with ErrorListPlot; otherwise it would have been easy.

If needed, I am using Mathematica 10.1.

Thanks in advance, regards

Jean-Philippe

PS: Here is the content of minimal (which is an imported simplified data file):

{{0.0626294, 9.1, 10.4523, 7.9, 0.52, 9.75, 12.73, 1.59, 9.21, 
  8.49, -19.7381}, {0.154463, 10.98, 2.43, 0.9158, 0.25, 12.33, 13.73,
   2.05, 7.59, 8.28, -12.479}, {0.0772834, 3.89214, 5.45804, 1.1667, 
  0.09, 6.51, 11.78, 1.22, 8.47, 8, -18.8248}, {0.084189, 3.7676, 
  0.714178, 0.9589, 0.64, 7.43, 9.85, 1.92, 8.07, 7.77, -17.4789}}

Comment: I miss the dear all; sorry

Comment: It is not quite clear, what are you after. I see at least two possibilities. A good idea would be, if you could post a plot like the one you need to obtain. Another good idea would be to define `minimal...`, otherwise we cannot really obtain your plot.

Comment: Can you plot -y[[]] instead of y[[]]? That turns it upside down as you desire. Then redefine the y axis labels?

Comment: I have just plotted the points were I have the maximum and minimum value for y. Actually I don't want to turn the y axis downward as it was already asked in other topics but just to have the higher value -12 at the place of -20 and vice versa; so to reverse the y axis

Comment: Does [this solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5718/21750) not work for you?

Comment: @2012rcampion, no I saw that topic already and there is no solution working for me. I tried to use Transpose, and also the solution with ScalingFunctions, but as I said in my post, it doesn't work, curiously, for ErrorListPlot. But it works for ListPlot and Plot (I have already used them).

Comment: @Bill, what do you mean by redefine the y axis labels?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeFontaine Bill means use the option [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html).

Comment: Folks, I think this might require some major surgery. As near as I can tell `ErrorListPlot` doesn't support either `Ticks` or `ScalingFunctions` as options.

Answer (score 4):

Does this look right?

```
Graphics[
 Scale[First@minimalplot, {1, -1}, {0, 0}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {1, -1} PlotRange[minimalplot],
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{-# &, -# &}], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> ({1, -1} # &), 
   "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({1, -1} # &)}
 Options[minimalplot]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above flips any `Graphics`.  Here is a more direct way for the OP's specific plot:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

minimalplot = 
 ErrorListPlot[
  Table[{{x[[i]], -y[[i]]}, ErrorBar[error[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[minimal]}],
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{-# &, -# &}], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
  CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> ({1, -1} # &), 
    "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({1, -1} # &)}
  ]
```

One can find several posts showing how to use `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` in [this site search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Charting+ScaledTicks).  Usage of `CoordinateToolOptions` may be explored in [this search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=CoordinatesToolOptions).

Comment: yes that is perfectly what I was seeking. Thanks a lot ! It is still strange that in the ErrorListPlot function, we can't use any ScalingFunctions like ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"} as in ListPlot.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeFontaine You're welcome. Yes, it seems an oversight to me, too.  Perhaps since ErrorListPlot is in a separate package, it has not kept up with the advances in the other plotting functions.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeFontaine Added support for copying coordinates (right-click the graphics), in case you or others want all the features `Graphics` are supposed to have.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Yes, you have to load ``Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]`` (acc. to docs.).  I should probably add that.  Yes, ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` is in blue; probably because it is an undefined head representing a data structure that is processed internally -- but that's my own guess at hidden internal details.  I'm on 10.2, too (OSX).  I don't get any error.  It's hard to read the error you posted (put it between double-backticks or post an image, maybe).

Comment: Your second version works fine for me so it must not be related to `Charting ScaledTicks`. I probably made some other mistake. I really like the general approach you show and how this could conceivably applied to any Graphic.

Answer (score 4):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

minimal = {{0.0626294, 9.1, 10.4523, 7.9, 0.52, 9.75, 12.73, 1.59, 9.21, 
    8.49, -19.7381}, {0.154463, 10.98, 2.43, 0.9158, 0.25, 12.33, 13.73, 2.05,
     7.59, 8.28, -12.479}, {0.0772834, 3.89214, 5.45804, 1.1667, 0.09, 6.51, 
    11.78, 1.22, 8.47, 8, -18.8248}, {0.084189, 3.7676, 0.714178, 0.9589, 
    0.64, 7.43, 9.85, 1.92, 8.07, 7.77, -17.4789}};
```

The definitions for `x`, `y`, and `error` can be simplified using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and the fact that [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html).

```
x = Log[10, minimal[[All, 2]]];

y = minimal[[All, 11]];

error = Log[10, minimal[[All, 3]]];

plotData2 = Transpose[{Transpose[{x, -y}], ErrorBar /@ error}];

minimalplot = ErrorListPlot[
  plotData2,
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> {12, 21},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic,
    Flatten[{
      {#, ""} & /@ Range[12, 21, 1/2],
      {#, -#} & /@ Range[12, 21, 2]}, 1],
    Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` support `ScalingFunctions->"Reverse"` one could use those functions.

The problem would be to create your own lines for the error bars.

This was done in the `makeErrorLines` function below.

**The Data**

I used your data except I replaced a negative error with it's positive counterpart.

```
x = {0.959041, 1.0406, 0.590188, 0.576065};
y = {-19.7381, -12.479, -18.8248, -17.4789};
error = {1.01921, 0.385606, 0.737037, 0.146194};
```

These x, y and error values were grouped together into `data`, `{{x,y}, error}`

```
data = Flatten[{Transpose[{x, y}], error}, {{2}, {1}}]

(* {{{0.959041, -19.7381}, 1.01921}, {{1.0406, -12.479}, 
  0.385606}, {{0.590188, -18.8248}, 0.737037}, {{0.576065, -17.4789}, 
  0.146194}} *)
```

**makeErrorLines**

This function was supplied with the ability to adjust the length of the line (default 1) and the horizontal bar length (default 0.003).

```
makeErrorLines[data_, scaleY_: 1, xOffset_: 0.003] := Flatten[
  Map[
   Function[dataPoint,
    With[
     {
      x = dataPoint[[1, 1]],
      y = dataPoint[[1, 2]],
      error = dataPoint[[2]]
      },
     {
      {{x, y - scaleY*error}, {x, y + scaleY*error}},
      {{x - xOffset, y + scaleY*error}, {x + xOffset, y + scaleY*error}},
      {{x - xOffset, y - scaleY*error}, {x + xOffset, y - scaleY*error}}
      }
     ]
    ],
   data
   ],
  1]
```

**Apply and Plot**

```
errorLines = makeErrorLines[data];
```

Now plot it using `ScalingFunctions-> "Reverse"`.

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[errorLines,
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
   Frame -> True,
  ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse"],
 ListPlot[
  data[[All, 1]],
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Red},
  ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse"
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]