# Change Orientation of List Plot Y Axis

Tags: plotting

i have some c++ output (just two coordinates of one point on each line in a a .csv file)  that i want to evaluate using *Mathematica*.

those points correspond to matrix elements. so i want my `ListPlot` to start in the left top corner with coordinates (0,0)
but i found no nice way to flip the orientation of the Y-axis.

my workaround so far is to change every y coordinate of all points to -y so it counts down. but thats very unclean.

```
ListPlot[{dataq0, dataq1}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> Automatic]
```

[image: this is how it looks now with y=-y]

the second thing, but that is not that important would be to have the X-axis on top of the plot.

if one of you knows how to do such
- help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`: from [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) "ArrayPlot[array] by default arranges successive rows of array down the page and successive columns across, just as a table or grid would normally be formatted".

Comment: Are you sure you want `ListPlot` and not `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`? They have the ordering in the way you want. To get the `Ticks` only to the correct edges look up `FrameTicks` option, which allows you to specify different settings for different sides.

Comment: i was thinking about Array/Matrix Plot but the structure of my import has the form:

http://i.imgur.com/3wNttA0.png

so its {{x1,x2}, ... ,{xn,yn}}
- and it would need some sophisticated way to convert it into a matrix-form where every entry corresponds to how often said point was found in the dataset.

Comment: This question has been answered before [flipping y axis](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96688/flipping-y-axis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) doesn't reveal it, but it can also be used for [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html). There is only one difference compared to the examples in the documentation, it has to be used as an option to the [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) option of `ListPlot`.
One can use the option `FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {None, All}}` to get "the X-axis on top of the plot".

```
dataq0 = RandomInteger[{0, 16}, {250, 2}];
dataq1 = RandomInteger[{0, 15}, {250, 2}];

ListPlot[{dataq0, dataq1}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 Frame -> True, Method -> ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {None, All}}]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: AMAZING

Method -> ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}

did exactly what i was looking for.

thanks alot!

cheers