# Flipping y-axis and keeping x-axis ticks and label on top

Tags: plotting

Consider the following plot:

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

How can the plot be inverted in the `y` axis such that the `x` axis ticks and label will remain on top, for example

[image]

There are two posts with similar questions, but they do not keep the `x` axis on top and seem to not use *Mathematica*'s abilities to their full extent so I did not find them useful:

- [flipping y axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96688/flipping-y-axis)
- [Switching direction of y-axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120991/switching-direction-of-y-axis)

Comment: [How to reverse the direction of the y axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41025/34893).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, All}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
                     {Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], Automatic}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {None, "x"}}]
```

or

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, All}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {1, Automatic}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {None, "x"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The frame label of the x axis appears below in the first suggestion, and don't appear at all in the second when adding FrameLabel->{"x","y"}. Can you address that in your answer?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the internal functions `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and  `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` to draw ticks with or without labels:

```
Plot[
    x,
    {x, 1, 10},
    Frame -> True, 
    ScalingFunctions->"Reverse",
    FrameTicks -> {
        {Automatic, Automatic},
        {
            Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}], 
            Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}]
        }
    }
]
```

[image]