# Combine two mirror plots

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I am trying to get something like this:[image: pic]

It resembles the [political compass](https://www.politicalcompass.org/). There are 4 axis, all of them always positive, and two curves are shown. One of them obeys the equation:

$d(M)=M^{0.2}$

and for the other:

$d(M)=M^{-0.2}$.

There are also two horizontal lines for $d=1$. And the origin of the graph is at $(1,0)$. The two curves are flipped like the picture. It would look nicer if the left and right sides of the graph had different background colors, like red and blue. How can I do that?

Comment: The bottom right curve is $M^{-0.2}$ flipped around $d=1$ and the top left curve is $M^{0.2}$ flipped around $M=0$, but I am chopping off the gap and only showing the curves for $M>1$. I can do all the flipping without setting the origin to $(1,0)$, but it looks a little weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, in fact, turns out to be possible. By combining s0rce's answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot) with Jens' `plotGrid` function from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately/6882#6882), we get:

```
pl1 = Plot[
  m^0.2, {m, 0, 5},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 2}},
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{1, 1}, {-5, 1}}]},
  Background -> LightBrown
  ]

pl2 = Plot[{}, {x, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 2}},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  Axes -> True,
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{1, 1}, {5, 1}}]},
  Background -> LightOrange
  ]

pl3 = Plot[{}, {x, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 2}},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Reverse"},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  Axes -> True,
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{1, -1}, {-5, -1}}]},
  Background -> LightYellow
  ]

pl4 = Plot[
  m^(-0.2), {m, 1, 5},
  ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse",
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 2}},
  Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{1, -1}, {5, -1}}]},
  Background -> LightBlue
  ]

plotGrid[{{pl1, pl2}, {pl3, pl4}}, 500, 300, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is beautiful, thanks :D

Comment: Ops, I think I have a problem. Mathematica won't accept the ScalingFunctions option :(

Comment: @RodrigoGalvão What version of Mathematica?

Comment: Version is 10.0

Comment: @RodrigoGalvão ok, I tried in Mathematica 10 and it does mark `ScalingFunctions` red, which it doesn't in Mathematica 11, but the code still works. Remember that you also have to define Jens' function `plotGrid` before you can run it. `ScalingFunctions`, as is noted in s0rce's answer, is an undocumented function. Officially it doesn't exist, so it's not completely surprising that it is colored in red.

Comment: Ok, I got the correct output now :)

Comment: Ops, upon a closer look, I found out there is something very wrong with pl1. Your plot looks fine, but mine looks like a straight line.                  pl1 = Plot[m^(0.2), {m, 1, 5}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse"}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 2}}, 
   Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{1, 1}, {-5, 1}}]}, 
   Background -> LightGreen];

Comment: @RodrigoGalvão I agree, there is something wrong in Mathematica 10. If you need to render this plot, then I would suggest using [Wolfram Open Cloud](https://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/). It uses the latest Mathematica version and you can get access for free. (I tried it just now to make sure that it works there.)