# Plot mirror-symmetric plots relative to x=a

Tags: plotting

I have explicit expressions of six functions and I can plot them From 0 to 2.0 by plotting command:

```
p2 = Plot[{0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1), 0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004), 
  1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08), Abs[0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1)], 
 Abs[0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004)], Abs[1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08)]}, 

{x, 0, 2.0}, 

  PlotRange -> {{0, 4.0}, {0, 8 \[Pi]}}, 

Exclusions -> {x == 1},

Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {Column[{Style["X", 17, Italic]}], 
Column[{Style["Y", 15, Italic]}]}]
```

But I wish to have mirror-symmetric plots of these six plots relative to `x=2` . The desired shape is as:

[image]

Black ones which are desired have been plotted by paint. How can I do this aim by *Mathematica* ?

Comment: Related: [146900](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146900/731)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
f = {0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1), 0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004), 
   1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08), Abs[0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1)], 
   Abs[0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004)], Abs[1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08)]};
g = f /. x -> (4 - x);
p2 = Show[
  Plot[f, {x, 0, 2.0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4.0}, {0, 8 \[Pi]}}, 
   Exclusions -> {x == 1}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {Column[{Style["X", 17, Italic]}], 
     Column[{Style["Y", 15, Italic]}]}],
  Plot[g, {x, 2, 4},Exclusions -> {x == 3}]
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ReflectionTransform` on `p2`:

```
Show[p2, MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}, {2, 0}]] &, p2, {1}]]
```

[image]