# Invert 3D surface plot and add custom Y-axis ticks labels

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling

I have the following data set:

```
dat = Dataset[{{1, 80, 57.}, {1, 90, 42.05}, {1, 95, 33.8}, {1, 97.5,
 28.18}, {1, 100, 25.4}, {1, 102.5, 25.83}, {1, 105, 28.54}, {1, 
110, 35.32}, {1, 120, 41.55}, {2, 80, 46.89}, {2, 90, 33.91}, {2, 
95, 25.92}, {2, 97.5, 21.51}, {2, 100, 19.52}, {2, 102.5, 
19.69}, {2, 105, 21.36}, {2, 110, 27.18}, {2, 120, 33.93}, {3, 80,
 40.78}, {3, 90, 29.04}, {3, 95, 23.53}, {3, 97.5, 20.88}, {3, 
100, 19.32}, {3, 102.5, 18.97}, {3, 105, 19.73}, {3, 110, 
23.36}, {3, 120, 28.33}, {4, 80, 37.05}, {4, 90, 26.22}, {4, 95, 
22.38}, {4, 97.5, 20.7}, {4, 100, 19.58}, {4, 102.5, 19.08}, {4, 
105, 19.15}, {4, 110, 20.48}, {4, 120, 23.74}, {5, 80, 36.25}, {5,
 90, 26.41}, {5, 95, 22.52}, {5, 97.5, 21.19}, {5, 100, 
20.36}, {5, 102.5, 19.96}, {5, 105, 19.93}, {5, 110, 20.79}, {5, 
120, 24.52}, {6, 80, 34.18}, {6, 90, 25.45}, {6, 95, 22.22}, {6, 
97.5, 21.23}, {6, 100, 20.66}, {6, 102.5, 20.41}, {6, 105, 
20.37}, {6, 110, 20.63}, {6, 120, 22.12}, {7, 80, 31.7}, {7, 90, 
24.94}, {7, 95, 22.45}, {7, 97.5, 21.61}, {7, 100, 21.04}, {7, 
102.5, 20.71}, {7, 105, 20.56}, {7, 110, 20.68}, {7, 120, 
22.}, {8, 80, 30.27}, {8, 90, 24.9}, {8, 95, 22.89}, {8, 97.5, 
22.2}, {8, 100, 21.72}, {8, 102.5, 21.45}, {8, 105, 21.35}, {8, 
110, 21.51}, {8, 120, 22.82}, {9, 80, 29.75}, {9, 90, 26.16}, {9, 
95, 24.89}, {9, 97.5, 24.39}, {9, 100, 23.98}, {9, 102.5, 
23.64}, {9, 105, 23.39}, {9, 110, 23.13}, {9, 120, 23.72}, {10, 
80, 28.44}, {10, 90, 25.36}, {10, 95, 24.29}, {10, 97.5, 
23.84}, {10, 100, 23.45}, {10, 102.5, 23.1}, {10, 105, 
22.81}, {10, 110, 22.44}, {10, 120, 22.7}, {11, 80, 27.3}, {11, 
90, 24.79}, {11, 95, 23.84}, {11, 97.5, 23.44}, {11, 100, 
23.09}, {11, 102.5, 22.78}, {11, 105, 22.53}, {11, 110, 
22.17}, {11, 120, 22.15}, {12, 80, 27.47}, {12, 90, 25.43}, {12, 
95, 24.63}, {12, 97.5, 24.29}, {12, 100, 23.98}, {12, 102.5, 
23.71}, {12, 105, 23.47}, {12, 110, 23.13}, {12, 120, 23.02}, {13,
 80, 26.46}, {13, 90, 25.02}, {13, 95, 24.47}, {13, 97.5, 
24.22}, {13, 100, 23.98}, {13, 102.5, 23.75}, {13, 105, 
23.54}, {13, 110, 23.2}, {13, 120, 22.87}, {14, 80, 26.83}, {14, 
90, 25.43}, {14, 95, 24.89}, {14, 97.5, 24.66}, {14, 100, 
24.45}, {14, 102.5, 24.27}, {14, 105, 24.1}, {14, 110, 
23.85}, {14, 120, 23.58}, {15, 80, 26.79}, {15, 90, 25.63}, {15, 
95, 25.17}, {15, 97.5, 24.98}, {15, 100, 24.8}, {15, 102.5, 
24.64}, {15, 105, 24.5}, {15, 110, 24.27}, {15, 120, 24.01}, {16, 
80, 26.57}, {16, 90, 25.6}, {16, 95, 25.21}, {16, 97.5, 
25.04}, {16, 100, 24.89}, {16, 102.5, 24.75}, {16, 105, 
24.63}, {16, 110, 24.43}, {16, 120, 24.19}, {17, 80, 26.16}, {17, 
90, 25.44}, {17, 95, 25.15}, {17, 97.5, 25.02}, {17, 100, 
24.91}, {17, 102.5, 24.8}, {17, 105, 24.7}, {17, 110, 24.53}, {17,
 120, 24.3}, {18, 80, 25.94}, {18, 90, 25.35}, {18, 95, 
25.11}, {18, 97.5, 25.}, {18, 100, 24.9}, {18, 102.5, 24.81}, {18,
 105, 24.72}, {18, 110, 24.58}, {18, 120, 24.35}, {19, 80, 
25.81}, {19, 90, 25.3}, {19, 95, 25.09}, {19, 97.5, 25.}, {19, 
100, 24.91}, {19, 102.5, 24.82}, {19, 105, 24.75}, {19, 110, 
24.61}, {19, 120, 24.4}, {20, 80, 25.73}, {20, 90, 25.27}, {20, 
95, 25.08}, {20, 97.5, 24.99}, {20, 100, 24.91}, {20, 102.5, 
24.83}, {20, 105, 24.76}, {20, 110, 24.64}, {20, 120, 24.43}, {21,
 80, 25.67}, {21, 90, 25.25}, {21, 95, 25.07}, {21, 97.5, 
24.99}, {21, 100, 24.92}, {21, 102.5, 24.85}, {21, 105, 
24.78}, {21, 110, 24.66}, {21, 120, 24.46}, {22, 80, 25.64}, {22, 
90, 25.25}, {22, 95, 25.08}, {22, 97.5, 25.}, {22, 100, 
24.93}, {22, 102.5, 24.87}, {22, 105, 24.8}, {22, 110, 
24.69}, {22, 120, 24.5}, {23, 80, 25.61}, {23, 90, 25.24}, {23, 
95, 25.09}, {23, 97.5, 25.02}, {23, 100, 24.95}, {23, 102.5, 
24.88}, {23, 105, 24.82}, {23, 110, 24.71}, {23, 120, 24.53}, {24,
 80, 25.6}, {24, 90, 25.25}, {24, 95, 25.11}, {24, 97.5, 
25.04}, {24, 100, 24.97}, {24, 102.5, 24.91}, {24, 105, 
24.85}, {24, 110, 24.75}, {24, 120, 24.57}}]
```

I have created a 3D surface plot in Mathematica using

ListPlot3D[dat, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]]

I have rotated the produced graph, as that's how I want to output it. See the image below:

[image]

I want to edit two things to the graph:

1. I want the y-axis (the x-axis from the picture above) reverted, so that the values range from 80 - 120.
2. I want to add custom x-axis(the y-axis from the picture above) ticks labels. The labels are: {Aug-17, Aug-17, Sep-17, Sep-17, Sep-17, Sep-17, 3Q-17, Oct-17, Nov-17, Dec-17, Jan-18, Feb-18, Apr-18, Jun-18, Sep-18, Jan-19, 4Q-19, 4Q-20, 4Q-21, 4Q-22, 4Q-23, 4Q-24, 4Q-25, 4Q-26}. So I would like to substitute the x-values 1-24 with these labels.

Can anyone help me with the correct way to do it?

Comment: It will be easier for people to answer this question if you edit your question to include the code you used to generate the original plot.  You should also describe in more detail which $z$-axis values correspond to which labels.

Comment: I have provided the data that was used to produce the graph as well with the code to generate the plot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the undocumented `ScalingFunctions` trick described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot) (among other places on this site) doesn't seem to work for `ListPlot3D` in v10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v11.1,ScalingFunctions work well

```
ListPlot3D[dat, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], 


ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity},Ticks -> {Transpose@{Range@24, 
     ToString /@ {Aug - 17, Aug - 17, Sep - 17, Sep - 17, Sep - 17, 
       Sep - 17, 3 Q - 17, Oct - 17, Nov - 17, Dec - 17, Jan - 18, 
       Feb - 18, Apr - 18, Jun - 18, Sep - 18, Jan - 19, 4 Q - 19, 
       4 Q - 20, 4 Q - 21, 4 Q - 22, 4 Q - 23, 4 Q - 24, 4 Q - 25, 
       4 Q - 26}}, Automatic, Automatic}, 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12]]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFo5x.jpg