# How to Plot a function f[x] wirh x running from max to min?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a function f[x] so that argument x would go from larger x1 to smaller x2. However

```
Plot[Log[x], {x, 2, 0.1}]
```

draws the same picture as

```
Plot[Log[x], {x, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image]

See Figure below. I need x running from 2 on the left to 0.1 on the right.

Comment: Indeed, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity} solves my problem as proposed in  [Flipping axis on a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 Plot[Log[2 - x], {x, 0.1, 2}, 
Ticks -> {Table[{i, 2 - i}, {i, 0.1, 2, 0.2}], Automatic}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: This is possible solution but not what I am looking for.

Comment: Then you should explain more clearly, what are you after, and, maybe, give a drawing (a hand-drawing?).

Comment: Actually, your solution would be fine if Ticks->{..} will completely emulate automatically gemerated ticks including shorter intermediate ticks which go withoul labels.

Comment: Look, Igor, This was not the main question of your post. This you can easily do by hands. Just do construct the ticks of your liking.  This is trivial. I only gave a direction, where you can go.