# Flipping axis on a LogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I want to modify the question in [Flipping axis on a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot). **How to flip y-axes on a LogPlot?** In contrast to Plot, LogPlot does not allow for the ScalingFunctions option so that the first solution proposed in [Flipping axis on a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot) does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a custom [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) instead. For example, here is a log plot:

```
LogPlot[Abs[Gamma[z]], {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

To reverse the y-axis use a custom [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option to [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot):

```
Plot[Abs[Gamma[z]], {z, -5, 5}, ScalingFunctions -> {Minus @* Log, Exp @* Minus}]
```

[image]