# How to make a tight crop of a 3d plot?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I like Mathematica, but it's syntax baffles me.

I am trying to figure out how to minimize the whitespace around a graphic.

For example,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: 3d bounding box on]

Puts the 3d bounding box at the limits of the view. But if I don't show the 3d bounding box,

[image: 3d bounding box on]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: 3d bounding box off]

there is all this white space around the actual object.

Is there some way (syntax) that can put the view just around the visible objects?

## Edit in response to answers

Ok, from the below answers, I have two solutions; 1) use ImageCrop, or 2) use `Method->{"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`. However both of these options do a little something strange to the plot I want (maybe it is just a problem with the plot itself).

So the actual plot I am after is,

```
Module[{r = 1, \[Theta] = \[Pi]/2, \[CurlyPhi] = \[Pi]/6, \[Psi] = \[Pi]/12},
Framed@Show[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   {Arrowheads[.025],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.1, 0, 0}}], Text["x", {1.2, 0, 0}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.1, 0}}], Text["y", {0, 1.2, 0}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.1}}], Text["z", {0, 0, 1.2}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, r {Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
      Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]}}]},
   {Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}
   },
  Boxed -> False,
  ImageSize -> 600,
  PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, r}}
  ]]
 ]
```

[image]

Which has too much whitespace. If I replace `Framed@Show[` with `Framed@ImageCrop@Show[` I 
get,
[image]

which actually crops some of the (hemi)sphere. If just use `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},` in the `Show` options, I get,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which looks almost correct, but the `x` and `z` textboxes have now not included. Seems like I can't win!

Comment: You've tried `PlotRangePadding -> None` and `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`?

Comment: Hi @J.M., `PLotRangePadding-> None` didn't seem to do much, but the `Method` option did (so thanks!). I'm curious though, how was I ever supposed to find this in the help? This is what I mean by not understanding Mathematica syntax.

Comment: @ShaunH You can find it here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/193

Comment: @J.M. I think that one is good enough for an answer

Comment: @J.M. I should stop answering questions. Where did you dig this up?

Comment: @hal, I don't know which of you guys told me about this, but I'm sure it was one of you...

Comment: @bel, maybe you can edit it into your answer instead. :)

Comment: @Shaun, it is a bit infuriating that a fair amount of useful *Mathematica* functions are poorly documented, or not documented at all. That bit has been mentioned a number of times on this site; search around...

Comment: @J.M. Nah, post that and I'll delete my answer.That is what the OP wanted. If I only could remember all the jungle of functions and methods

Comment: `ImageCrop` has a bug in some 8.0x versions when it comes to lightly coloured areas sometimes. Try something like `imcrop[img_] := ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]` instead.

Comment: I believe I've found a small hack to get the `ShrinkWrap` option approach working: I placed white points with `Opacity[0.01]` just past each of my axis labels (or other text that's being cut-off). I'm running *Mathematica* 10.2. P.S. I don't have the 50 reputation points needed to post a response in the appropriate place above, but solving this was very useful to me and perhaps will be to others, so I'm posting it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, there isn't white space at all:

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[True, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
                  PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None, 
                  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0], 
     ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi} ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

If you want to crop the image in **2D**:

```
p = ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
Framed@ImageCrop@p
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

For your plot. Use .2 as `Opacity`. It has been reported elsewhere in this site that lowering the opacity too much makes other functions unable to detect the object.

```
Module[{r = 
   1, \[Theta] = \[Pi]/2, \[CurlyPhi] = \[Pi]/6, \[Psi] = \[Pi]/12},
 Framed@ImageCrop@Show[
    Graphics3D[
     {{Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[.2], 
       Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}, {Arrowheads[.025], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.1, 0, 0}}], Text["x", {1.2, 0, 0}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.1, 0}}], Text["y", {0, 1.2, 0}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.1}}], Text["z", {0, 0, 1.2}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 
         r {Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
           Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]}}]}}, 
     Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
     PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, r}}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @belisarius, fine, it is not whitespace. But this doesn't answer the question of how to make a tight crop around just the object(s).

Comment: @ShaunH The crop IS tight, but in 3D.

Comment: that definitely helps, but in the plot that I am after, it crops some of the object (see my edit to the question).

Comment: @ShaunH See edit

Comment: haha, ok cool, so changing the opacity of the sphere fixes it. Why didn't I think of that! Cheers.

Comment: The cropped half-sphere image still seems to be cut off by a few pixels on the lower border...

Comment: I think this method rasterizes the vector graphics! right?

Answer (score 12):

I think what you are looking for is [**ViewAngle**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewAngle.html) option. The graph below compares default `Automatic` versus custom setting for `ViewAngle`. The image are framed intentionally to see clearly the removal of surrounding white space.

```
Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0] & /@ 
     (ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], r^2}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
        Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
        ImageSize -> 350 {1, 1}, ViewAngle -> #] & /@ {Automatic, .31})
```

[image]

Mathematica has rich set of options for so called "simulated camera" that "views" all 3D objects. To learn in detail about this i suggest downlading notebbok and watching free video of the @Yu-SungChang course [**Lights, Camera, Graphics!**](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2011/presentations/) . Here is a illustrious diagram from that course explaining how `ViewAngle` option (measured in your example in 0.31 radians) sets up the view of a 3D objects.

[image]

You actually can change the `ViewAngle` setting interactively by holding CTRL or ALT key and dragging graphics with mouse - this effectively zooms in or out. See [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/RotateZoomAndPanGraphics.html) for details.

Comment: You should point out, that this does not work automatically and that you have to adjust this for different viewing positions. But when I think about it: maybe the OP wasn't really interested in a `Cropping->All` solution and is fine to adjust it manually. 1+

Answer (score 2):

`ImageCrop` seems to be a bit buggy (at least right here in Version 8.04, Win 64). It tends to crop lightly coloured areas rather agressively. You could try the following work-around, which works more reliably:

```
imcrop[img_] := ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img, 0]]

g = Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[.1], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}
   ];
Column[Framed /@ {g, ImageCrop[g], imcrop[g]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your graphics it seems to work without additional changes to `Opacity` or similar:

```
g = Module[{r = 
     1, \[Theta] = Pi/2, \[CurlyPhi] = Pi/6, \[Psi] = Pi/12},
    Show[Graphics3D[{{Arrowheads[.025], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.1, 0, 0}}], Text["x", {1.2, 0, 0}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.1, 0}}], Text["y", {0, 1.2, 0}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.1}}], Text["z", {0, 0, 1.2}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 
         r {Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
           Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
           Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]}}]}, {Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[.1],
        Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
     PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, r}}]]];    

Framed@imcrop[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]