# How do I automatically "trim" the bounding box for a Graphics3D output?

Tags: graphics3d

I noticed that, provided some Graphics3D output scaled with ImageSize, I can get rid of a lot of the empty space around the graphic by right-clicking and then selecting "Trim Bounding Box".  Thinking that it would be nice to have this done automatically, I looked through the Mathematica manual, but I couldn't find a way of accomplishing this.

How might I set a toggle so that "Trim Bounding Box" is automatic?

Comment: What happens if you add the option `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`?

Comment: [Related?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10427/61)

Comment: @J.M. What happens is that it fixes the problem and works great.

Comment: @J.M. How did you find out how to do that?  I perpetually have trouble finding these things.

Comment: Some ways to find hidden options: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/131