# Control parameters of different styles of DistributionChart

Tags: plotting, charts

Using `DistributionChart`, you can choose among several styles aka `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ChartElementData["DistributionChart"]

{"Density", "DensityQuantile", "FadingQuantile",
 "GlassQuantile", "HistogramDensity", "LineDensity", "PointDensity", 
 "Quantile", "SmoothDensity"}
```

Is there a way to control their parameters? The documentation does not seem to say.

---

The problem is that the defaults are less than optimal for [my data](http://pastebin.com/KStzqPA3). Consider these:

Using `SmoothDensity`:

[image: SmoothDensity]

Using `HistogramDensity`:

[image: HistogramDensity]

Using `LineDensity`:

[image: <code>LineDensity</code>]

Clearly, `SmoothDensity` grossly misrepresents the data (just compare with the `LineDensity` version); the violins should all look like the ones for 2 and 9. `HistogramDensity` does a better job but its resolution is horrible; there are 100 data points per size, about 70 of which fall into the upper class -- that should be plenty of points to draw more bars.

I would like to tell `HistogramDensity` to use more/smaller bins, and/or `SmoothDensity` to smooth less. How is this possible?

Comment: We briefly tried writing our own `ChartElementFunction`, but that turned out to be very daunting indeed.

Comment: Re: your comment on the blogpost, I left you a reply there, but am commenting here again because I don't know if you'll be pinged/emailed for that or not. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/5) for ways to find undocumented options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the options available for various `ChartElementDataFunction`s you can use:

```
 {#, Column[ChartElementData[#, "Options"]]} & /@ 
   ChartElementData["DistributionChart"] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

---

For `"HistogramDensity"`, **any** bin specification accepted by [`Histogram > MoreInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html) can be used as the setting for the suboption `"Bins"`:

> [image]

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], 100], {3}];

Partition[Table[DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> "SolarColors",
ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction["HistogramDensity", "Bins" -> i]),
PlotLabel -> Row[{"\"Bins\"", "->", ToString@i}], ImageSize -> 200],
{i, {10, 5, {.3}, {0, 8, .5}, {{0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8}},
 Automatic, "Sturges", "Scott", "FreedmanDiaconis", "Knuth", 
 "Wand", "Log",
 {"Log", "Sturges"}, {"Log", "Scott"}, {"Log", 
  "FreedmanDiaconis"}, {"Log", "Knuth"}}}], 4] //
Grid[#, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 5] &
```

[image]

... including custom bin specifications like

```
binFunc1 = Union[IntegerPart[#]] &;
binFunc2 = Quantile[#, {0, .05, .1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95, 1.}] &;
binFunc3 = First[HistogramList[#, "FreedmanDiaconis"]] &;
binFunc4 = Sort@#[[RandomSample[Range@Length@#, 10]]] &;

Partition[Table[DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
 ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction[
   "HistogramDensity", "Bins" -> i]),
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"\"Bins\"", "->\n", ToString@i}], 
 ImageSize -> 300],
 {i, {binFunc1, binFunc2, binFunc3, binFunc4}}], 2] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 5] &
```

[image]

---

For `"Quantile"`, `"FadingQuantile"`, `"GlassQuantile"` and `"DensityQuantile"`,  the settings for suboption `"Quantile"` can be either an integer `n` (short for the `n-1` quantiles `100 i/n (i = 1, ... , n-1)` or an explicit list of integers between `0` and `100`. Furthermore, each of the explicitly specified quantiles can be styled  individually using the suboption `"QuantileStyle"`.

```
Partition[Table[DistributionChart[data, 
ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction["GlassQuantile",
   "Quantile" -> i,
   "QuantileStyle" -> (Directive[Thick, Hue[#/100]] & /@ i),
   "QuantileShading" -> True]),
PlotLabel -> Row[{"Quantiles:  ", ToString@i}], ImageSize -> 300],
{i, {4, {25, 50, 75}, {10, 90}, {5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95}}}], 2] //
Grid[#, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 5] &
```

[image]

---

The option setting for  `"Threshold"` seems to control symmetric trimming at the two tails as the following examples suggest. (Perhaps, further fishing may reveal that it accepts additional values to control the bandwidths)

```
Row@Table[DistributionChart[data, 
 ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity", 
  "ColorScheme" -> "DeepSeaColors", "Threshold" -> i]), 
 ImageSize -> 300], {i, {.05, .1, .5}}]
```

[image]

```
Row@Table[DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> "SolarColors", 
 ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction["Density", "Threshold" -> i]),
 ImageSize -> 300], {i, {.05, .1, .5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to post a "Please teach me how to catch the fish!" comment, but you were faster. Awesome, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a parameter suitable for making the (smooth) charts match the data better; `Threshold` only controls the fraction of data used at all. (By the way, how do you find out which values are valid for e.g. `Shape`?)

Comment: @Raphael, as far as I know there is no organized documentation _yet_ on these `"Options"`. Some possible settings for few of these options are in the `Chart Element Schemes` palette as drop-down choices.