# Change ColorScheme of DistributionChart

Tags: plotting, color

The `"ColorScheme"`of a DistributionChart can be changed using the `ChartElementFunction` like in the following example:

```
SeedRandom["DistributionChart"];
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {100}];

DistributionChart[data, 
  ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementData["SmoothDensity", "ColorScheme" -> "DeepSeaColors"]]
```

[image]

But the `"ColorScheme"`seems to get irgnored if I change `"SmoothDensity"` for `"DensityQuantile"`

I tried to change the colors using `ChartStyle` but I only got the following, unsatisfactory result.

```
DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> "DeepSeaColors", 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementData["DensityQuantile"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `ChartStyle` does work, but it does not apply the whole colour range to the first bar.

This example, slightly modified from the documentation, shows what is actually going on.

```
Table[DistributionChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> f, 
  ChartStyle -> "DeepSeaColors"], {f, {"Quantile", "DensityQuantile", 
   "FadingQuantile", "GlassQuantile"}}]
```

[image]

Or even more simply:

```
DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> Darker@Blue, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementData["DensityQuantile"]]
```

[image]

To get something more like what you want will be tricky because `"DensityQuantile"` uses `Opacity` to make the outlying parts lighter, not darker as in the example for `"SmoothDensity"`.

Although there are many other [sub-options for these styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11100/8), not all well-documented, I couldn't find an obvious solution. This was the best I could do to get darker bands in the middle.

```
DistributionChart[data, ChartStyle -> ColorData["DeepSeaColors"], 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementData["Quantile", "Quantile" -> 8, 
   "QuantileShading" -> True]]
```

[image]