# Changing the inter-item spacing in Legends (version 9 and up)

Tags: legending

The legending functionality in versions 9 and higher is much easier to use than the `PlotLegends` package and other bespoke ways of creating legends in earlier versions. However, the vertical spacing between items is larger than I would like. How can I reduce this spacing?

Changing the `LegendMarkerSize` option to a smaller number without changing the size specified in the `LegendMarkers` option just ends up cutting off the graphic. `LegendMargins` doesn't affect the inter-item spacing, only the space between the whole legend and other items.

```
PointLegend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {"Series 1", "Series 2"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 19, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out that the `Spacings` option does exactly what is needed, even though its use in legend constructs such as `PointLegend` is not documented, and it shows as red text when you use it in those constructs.

```
PointLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"Series 1", "Series 2"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}}, 
 Spacings -> {0.2, 0.2}, LegendMarkerSize -> 19, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20}]
```

[image]

This continues the tradition of undocumented [options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/8) and [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/8) in Mathematica.

**UPDATE (2)**: the `Spacings` option is still marked with red text in version 10.0.1, 10.1 **and 10.3 and 11.0**.

Comment: I wished WRI would do once a "documentation release": no new features, just existing ones better, much better,documented.

Answer (score 9):

Another option, which I use now, is to use `Grid`. With `Grid` you have all the options that comes with `Grid` and hence you can build the legend in as many different ways as you wish.

```
Manipulate[

 plotLegend = 
  Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", LegendMargins -> 1, 
    LegendLayout -> Function[{x},
      Grid[x, Spacings -> {hspacing, vspacing}, Alignment -> Left, 
       Frame -> isFrame]]], location];

 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegends -> plotLegend, 
  ImageSize -> 300, ImageMargins -> 50, Frame -> True],
 Grid[{
   {"vertical spacing", 
    Control[{{vspacing, .1, ""}, 0, 3, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {"horizontal spacing", 
    Control[{{hspacing, .1, ""}, 0, 3, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {"add frame?", Checkbox[Dynamic[isFrame]], , SpanFromLeft},
   {"location?", PopupMenu[Dynamic[location, (location = #) &],
     {
      {Right, Top} -> Style["{Right,Top}", 12],
      Right -> Style["Right", 12],
      Left -> Style["Left", 12],
      {Right, Bottom} -> Style["{Right,Bottom}", 12],
      Above -> Style["Above", 12],
      Below -> Style["Below", 12]
      }], SpanFromLeft
    }
   }, Spacings -> {0, 1}, Alignment -> Left],
 {{location, {Right, Top}}, None},
 {{isFrame, True}, None}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For expressions, it works fine. But it is not working for Listplot. Can you please address it for Listplot?