# How to change the spacing of line in legend?

Tags: legending

Given this plot:

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  berea[[All, {1, 2}]]
  , beryl[[All, {1, 2}]]
  , graphite[[All, {1, 2}]]
  , nb[[All, {1, 2}]]
  , nu0[[All, {1, 2}]]
  , nunim[[All, {1, 2}]]
  }
 , Filling -> {5 -> {6}}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {
   "!(*SubscriptBox[\"a\", \" \ \"])/!(*SubscriptBox[\"b\", \" \"])", "[Chi]/!(*SuperscriptBox[\"[Chi]\", \"*\"])"
   }
 , RotateLabel -> False
 , PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Red}, Black, 
   Dashed, {DotDashed, Thick}, {Black, Thick}, {Black, Thick}}
 , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
 , PlotLegend -> {"Berea sandstone", "Beryl rock", "Graphite/epoxy", "Nb !(*SubscriptBox[\"Se\", \"2\"])", "[Nu]=0", "[Nu]=0.5"}
 , LegendShadow -> None
 , LegendPosition -> {-0.75, -0.225}
 , LegendBorder -> White
 , LegendBorderSpace -> Automatic
 , LegendTextSpace -> 3.25
 , LegendSpacing -> 0.1
 ]
```

How can I change the spacing of lines in the legend?

How to make the legend elements to be near to each other?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  Are you aware of the new built-in legending functionality, available since version 9?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You set the vertical spacing of the legends to 0.1 with `LegendSpacing -> 0.1` and you got  that spacing. If you want the legends closer together use a smaller value, say, .05

Comment: @Szabolcs: Hi there, can you kindly elaborate on this functionality via an answer. I am having the same problem in this question and I am not satisfied with the answer below. :)

Comment: @H.R. Can you explain what it wrong with the answer below? I meant exactly what Verbeia has shown.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I want to do this in a `Show` command. Furthermore, there are around 12 curves and when I do the solution suggested by Verbeia, the legends appear in two columns while there is enough space to put them into one. By the way, why `Spacings` turns into red while using it in `LineLegend`?

Comment: @H.R. I think it will be best if you ask a new question where you describe in detail the specific problems you encountered.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yeah. You are right. :)

Answer (score 20):

For completeness, I present how to do this in versions 9 and above, using the built-in legending functions. The trick is captured in a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17530/changing-the-inter-item-spacing-in-legends-version-9-and-up): use the `Spacings` option, even though it shows up as red when you use it in a `LineLegend` expression.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[PDF[BetaDistribution[2, j/3], i], {j, 1, 6, 1}, {i, 0.05, 0.95,
    0.05}], Filling -> {5 -> {6}}, Frame -> True, 
 RotateLabel -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Red}, Black, 
   Dashed, {DotDashed, Thick}, {Black, Thick}, {Black, 
    AbsoluteThickness[2]}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    Automatic, {"Berea sandstone", "Beryl rock", "Graphite/epoxy", 
     "NB", "\[Nu]=0", "\[Nu]=0.5"}, Spacings -> 0.15], {0.2, 0.8}], 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Something to note is that if you set the first argument of `LineLegend` to `Automatic`, you need to ensure that the line styles are distinct. Otherwise not all the lines will be legended.

Comment: And another undocumented option for `LineLegend`. -.- Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.