# Mathematica for teaching orthographic projection

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

**Edit**: *All the four answers to this question are great, and if you're interested, you should take a look at all the answers. Nevertheless, belisarius' code was accepted since it was closest to what I had in mind.*

I'm trying to use *Mathematica* to help students better understand 3-dimensional views of objects, specifically the "plan view", the "side elevation view" and the "front elevation view", as elaborated upon [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/3dshapesrev2.shtml).

Given the following example "building", I was able to combine `Graphics3D` primitives to simulate the object using the following code.

[image]

```
dee = Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[0.6], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}],
    Red, Polygon[{{{2/3, 1/2, 0}, {2/3, 1/2, 1}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}}, 
       {{2/3, 1, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}, {3/2, 1, 0}}, 
       {{2/3, 1/2, 0}, {2/3, 1, 0}, {3/2, 1, 0}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}}, 
       {{2/3, 1/2, 1}, {2/3, 1, 1}, {3/2, 1, 0}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}}}]}]
```

However, as you can see, the code is rather convoluted, with a great deal of time spent making the red prism. In this case, it was still feasible to manually generate the prism, but what I'm interested in is,

> Is there a way to generate a 3D object which is made up of a combination of prisms simply by identifying the vertices at the corner of the object?

---

If you're interested, my code to allow students to see the three views is as follows, with an example result below.

```
planviewer = 
  TableForm@{{"3d", "Side", "Front", "Top"}, 
    {Show[#, ViewPoint -> {1, -1, 1}], 
     Show[#, ViewPoint -> {∞, 0, 0}], 
     Show[#, ViewPoint -> {0, -∞, 0}], 
     Show[#, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}]}, 
    {"", 
     Show[#, ViewPoint -> Right], 
     Show[#, ViewPoint -> Front], 
     Show[#, ViewPoint -> Above]}} &;
```

[image]

The following code allows them to manipulate the viewpoint dynamically.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[dee, ViewPoint -> {10^a, -(10^b), 10^c}], {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}, {c, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: If you want to teach about the different `View*` functions and what they do, you might find [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5) useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some tricks ... Specifying the prism's vertices is enough (you don't need to take care of the faces) if you use some undocumented methods for finding the convex hull:

```
v = {{2/3, 1/2, 0}, {2/3, 1/2, 1}, {2/3, 1, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}, {3/2, 1, 0}};
prism@v_:=Cases[ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[v,Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces->False],
                                                                 _GraphicsComplex, Infinity];

Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[0.6], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}], Opacity[.6], Red, prism@v}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is easily turned into a function, `polyhedron[v_] := Cases[..`  Very nice. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! Rewritten as a function now.

Comment: @belisarius how do you find out about all these undocumented questions? I was trying to search for it, and saw some similar questions on this site, but I think that's the first time I've seen it. *Edit:* ninja'd by bill.

Comment: It's not on this list, by the way :) : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/809/how-can-one-find-undocumented-options-or-option-values-in-mathematica

Comment: @VincentTjeng I don't remember how I found this one, probably following some InternalTrace. You can find similar things trying ``Names["ComputationalGeometry`Methods`*"]``

Comment: @belisarius By the way (I'm not sure whether you know of this) but `TetGenLink` has a (documented) function `TetGenConvexHull` which allows one to achieve the same as what you've done :) http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/tutorial/UsingTetGenLink.html#381515433

Comment: @VincentTjeng They aren't completely equivalent. If you try it, you'll see the full facets triangulation, which is undesired here: `Needs["TetGenLink`"]
data3D = {{2/3, 1/2, 0}, {2/3, 1/2, 1}, {2/3, 1, 0}, {2/3, 1, 
    1}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}, {3/2, 1, 0}};
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[data3D];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]]`

Comment: good point! thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14):

`GraphicsComplex` is probably what you are looking for. For example, define the vertices for the 3D polygon:

```
v = {{2/3, 1/2, 0},{2/3, 1/2, 1},{3/2, 1/2, 0},{2/3, 1, 0},{2/3, 1, 1},{3/2, 1, 0}};
```

and make a list of which vertices should connect to each other:

```
i = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 5, 4}, {1, 3, 6, 4}, {2, 3, 6, 5}};
```

The first two elements of `i` represent the two triangular faces of the prism; the final three elements are the three rectangular faces. This is plotted using

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], Red, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]}]
```

or you can plot the green cube plus the red prism together:

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[0.6], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}], 
  Opacity[.6], Red, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]}]
```

which gives the figure below. The code is modified from the documentation in `GraphicsComplex` where you can find all sorts of neat 3D tricks. If they have access, I think the students would benefit from being able to manipulate the 3D illustration themselves -- this seems like a good application for deployed .cdf's.

[image: cube and prism]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would it be possible for the one to write some code that immediately identifies which of vertices should be connected to each other to form the faces, keeping in mind that the faces of the prism may not always be in the same plane? Also, I notice that the part of the red prism joining the green cuboid is actually a triangle, and not a rectangle ... is that a problem or simply a visual illusion?

Comment: The little triangle on the adjoining face is an illusion that has to do with the shading -- when you rotate the graphic it changes. But to your first question, the answer is no. After all, how can it know what edges you want to connect if you don't tell it? You will get *something* no matter what edges you connect -- only one of these is the figure you presumably want.

Comment: @VincentTjeng: yes, you can connect the vertices automagically because the faces must form the convex hull. See my answer

Comment: Very nice... how does one find "undocumented features"?

Comment: bill I don't remember how I found this one, probably following some InternalTrace. You can find similar things trying ``Names["ComputationalGeometry`Methods`*"]``

Answer (score 9):

**You can get away with specifying even less than all the points.**

A (right) prism is a planar figure extruded in an orthogonal direction.  It would suffice, then, to give the coordinates of that figure (thereby describing one of the two "ends" of the prism) and its intended height.  The figure in the question can therefore be created as a collection of two prisms (no `Cuboid` if you don't care to use it) like this:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], 
  Green, prism[{{0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 0, 0}, {2/3, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 1],
  Red, prism[{{2/3, 1, 0}, {3/2, 1, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}}, 1/2]}]
```

[image: Reproduction]

The calculations come down to

1. Find a basis for the polygon's plane by orthogonalizing its vertices relative to their barycenter;
2. Perform the extrusion by taking the cross product of the basis elements (normalized to the desired height) and adding that to each of the polygon's vertices; and
3. Describe how the vertices are connected to form the two polygonal ends and each of the sides.

Here is such a solution.  Its arguments are `pt`, a list of the (3D) vertices around the (nondegenerate) polygon, and `height`, the height of the prism.  It produces a 3D graphics object.

```
prism[pt_List, height_] := Block[{n = Length[pt], normal},
  normal = Cross @@ Orthogonalize[# - Mean[pt] & /@ pt][[1 ;; 2]];
  GraphicsComplex[pt~Join~(height normal + # & /@ pt), 
   {Polygon[Range[n]], Polygon[Range[2 n, n + 1, -1]], 
    Polygon[{#, n + #, n +  Mod[# + 1, n, 1], Mod[# + 1, n, 1]}] & /@ Range[n]}]]
```

To see it in action, let's generate a polygon with a random position and orientation:

```
basis = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {2, 3}];
pt = ({Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/7]).basis
```

Here is the original polygon as a solid black "floor" drawn with *two* prisms, one with a positive height and another with a negative height:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.75], prism[pt, 1], prism[pt, -1/2], Opacity[1], Black,  Polygon[pt]}]
```

[image: Prism]

This approach is easily extended to non-right prisms by replacing `height` by the extrusion vector (describing one of the "vertical" edges of the prism) and using that instead of `height normal` in the code.

Comment: nice application of math :) just a quick question, when you code as `prism[pt_List, height_]`, `pt_List` is written as such since it is a list, right? so if i were to code a function `f[a_String, b_String]`, then the variables would be `a, b` and they must be strings?

Comment: See [the documentation on `Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html).

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the output of `PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 3}, "Faces"]}`, which may help.

Note this isn't exactly a direct answer, but I think the optimal solution here is a tool that would let you... well, like this:

```
whatThe[n_] := Module[{list = {}, grid = False},
   Grid@List@{
      EventHandler[#, {"KeyDown", "k"} :> (grid = Not[grid])] &[

       Graphics3D[{
            EventHandler[MouseAppearance[Sphere[#, .06],
              Style["\[RightUpDownVector]\[LeftUpDownVector]", Darker@Blue, Large]],
            {"MouseClicked" :> AppendTo[list, ##]}] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], 3],

         (*Opacity[.3],*)Dynamic[Polygon[list]], Thick, Dynamic[Line[list]],
         Thin, Lighter[Gray, .8], Dynamic[If[grid, Line[                
            Select[Subsets[Tuples[Range[n], 3], {2}],
             EuclideanDistance @@ ## == 1 &]], {}]]},

        Boxed -> True, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]],

      Graphics3D[Dynamic[Polygon[list]]], 
      EventHandler[Dynamic[Column[list]],
       {"MouseClicked" :> (CopyToClipboard[list]; Beep[])}]}
   ];

whatThe[4]
```

You click on points to add them to a list. MAGIC!!! It takes some getting used to... here's one of my attempts at creating a prism:

[image]

I couldn't tell what order you have to construct the list in for the resulting polygon to be reasonable, but at the very least it might help you pick some points out. It's also another example of just how ridiculously powerful Mathematica is. The basic working version of this took me like 4 minutes to make. O.O

(Note: A simple improvement might be to use a hotkey to cut the list up as you build the polygon).

**Update.** Using belisarius's convex hull code:

```
whatThe[n_] := Module[{list = {}, faces, grid = False},
   faces[v_] := Cases[ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[v, 
      Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces -> False], _GraphicsComplex, Infinity];

   Grid@List@{
      EventHandler[#, {"KeyDown", "k"} :> (grid = Not[grid])] &[

       Graphics3D[{EventHandler[
            MouseAppearance[Sphere[#, .06], 
             Style["\[RightUpDownVector]\[LeftUpDownVector]", 
              Darker@Blue, Large]],
            {"MouseClicked" :> AppendTo[list, ##]}] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], 3],

         (*Opacity[.3],*)Dynamic[faces[list]],
         Thin, Lighter[Gray, .8], Dynamic[If[grid, Line[
            Select[Subsets[Tuples[Range[n], 3], {2}], 
             EuclideanDistance @@ ## == 1 &]], {}]]},

        Boxed -> True, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]],

      Graphics3D[Dynamic[faces[list]]],
      EventHandler[Dynamic[Column[list]],
       {"MouseClicked" :> (CopyToClipboard[list]; Beep[])}]}];
```

[image]

Comment: +1 amazing. and it helps with the first part of translating the problems in the students' worksheets to the prism I want. now I just need to modify the code such that it accepts multiple convex hulls representing the multiple prisms :)

Answer (score 2):

`Prism` is built in as of version 10.0:

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[0.6], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}], Red, 
  Prism[{{2/3, 1/2, 0}, {2/3, 1/2, 1}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}, 
   {2/3, 1, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}, {3/2, 1, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In version 12 (possibly in versions 10+), the option `FlatFaces -> False` works with `ConvexHullMesh` (despite red syntax highlighting):

```
v = {{2/3, 1/2, 0}, {2/3, 1/2, 1}, {2/3, 1, 0}, {2/3, 1, 1}, {3/2, 1/2, 0}, {3/2, 1, 0}};

ConvexHullMesh[v,  FlatFaces -> False, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thick, Black], 2 -> Opacity[.5, Red]}]
```

[image]