# How to use Undocumented Functions Prism, Tetrahedron and Hexahedron

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry

Taking a look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29721/how-to-plot-prism-in-graphics3d) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22349/mathematica-for-teaching-orthographic-projection/22385#22385), I checked to see if *Mathematica* really does not have a `Prism` primitive. To my surprise the function `Prism` was black but hitting the `F1` key didn't bring up anything useful. I also stumbled upon `Tetrahedron` and `Hexahedron` as being undocumented too. So how can one properly use these functions? If these functions have already been unearthed please forgive me as I could not find any usage of them here.

Comment: These functions are all documented in V10.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll show some examples of using the undocumented function `Prism`. `Tetrahedron` and `Hexahedron` are very similar.

First some points:

```
g = {{4, 2, 4}, {2, 2, 2}, {6, 2, 2}, {4, 6, 4}, {2, 6, 2}, {6, 6, 2}}
p = Prism[g];
```

We can use `p` directly in `Graphics3D` e.g.

```
Graphics3D[p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or more fancy stuff:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker@Green}], 
  FaceForm[{Lighter@Yellow, Opacity[0.3]}], p}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Doing `?Prism` reveals it has the following `Options`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Here I show how to use `Tetrahedron` to generate a 3D Delaunay tetrahedralization:

First we load `TeTGenLink` package

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
```

Then we generate some points in 3D

```
pts3d = RandomReal[3, {50, 3}];
```

We tetrahedralize:

```
{ptstg, tetrahedra} = TetGenDelaunay[pts3d];
tetra = pts3d[[#]] & /@ tetrahedra;
```

Now the plot:

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[{Thin, Darker@Blue}], 
   FaceForm[Yellow], Tetrahedron[tetra]}, {PointSize[0.02], Red, 
   Point[pts3d]}}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Will Be included in V10**

As I was writing this up I looked online in the new Wolfram documentation and it turns out these functions will be officially included in the upcoming v10. If you want to see how `Tetrahedron` and `Hexahedron` are used please see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hexahedron.html) and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tetrahedron.html) respectively. Note that some of the functionalities shown there are not implemented in current versions of *Mathematica*

Comment: Regarding the edit: You can actually try these using the [programming cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/).