# How to compute this triple integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

In **Mathematica** how can I compute this integral:$$ \iiint_{D}\sqrt{(1-9z^2)(1-4y^2-9z^2)}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where D is the domain:

$$D: x^2 +4y^2+9z^2\le1$$

Please I need help!!!

Comment: I asked how to in fact...

Comment: Where.., there are `Integrate` `Sqrt` and all.. :)

Comment: I know...but which is the syntax I've to use?

Comment: Yeah...but no one talks about triple integrals

Comment: Please, check the documentation of `Integrate`. Specifically, look into the Scope section, subsection Integrals over Regions

Comment: thank you...I'll inform you when i find something

Comment: Can be this correct?   Integrate[(Sqrt[(1 - 9 z^2) (1 - 9 z^2 - 4 y^2)]) Boole[-Sqrt[
      1 - x^2 - 4 y^2]/3 <= z <= Sqrt[1 - x^2 - 4 y^2]/3], {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, {z, -1/3, 1/3}]

Comment: Only for the sake of math: it you redefine variables as $X=x$, $Y=2y$ and $Z=3z$, you see that the domain is a sphere!

Comment: Just use your domain exactly as you specified it in the question as an argument of `Boole`. Don't make it more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps too "creative". Some health checks needed for the series behavior:

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];
region = (x x + 4 y y + 9 z z <= 1);
paregion = Region`ParametricRegion[{{x, y, z}, region}];
k = FullSimplify@
     Normal@Series[Sqrt[(1-9 z^2) (1-9 z^2-4 y^2)], {z,0, #},{y,0, #}] &/@ Range[1, 10, 2];
res = N@Integrate[#, {x, y, z} ∈ paregion] & /@ k

(* {0.698132, 0.488692, 0.480154, 0.477423, 0.476201} *)
```

So the result is near to 0.476

```
ListLinePlot@res
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48166/193) is where I've read first about this way for using `Integrate[]`

Comment: I don't think this is the most practical way to integrate this. I'm posting it more as a curiosity.

Comment: +1 for the undocumented integrate use :)

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks for remembering me that! Added a link.

Answer (score 4):

I just did this:

```
Integrate[Boole[x^2 + 4*y^2 + 9*z^2 <= 1]*
 Sqrt[(1 - 9*z^2)*(1 - 4*y^2 - 9*z^2)], {z, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]},{y, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}, {x, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
```

MMA quickly returned

```
64/135
```

Comment: The order in which you did the integrations is important — doing `x` then `y` then `z` gives the quickest route through the nested integral. Other orderings seem not to evaluate.

Comment: Heh. Sometimes it's better to be lucky than to be smart!