# Compute Triple Integral on spherical coords

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to compute: $\int \int \int  z  dxdydz$

over the domain: $\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leqslant 16,z\geqslant 0\}$

Im trying to use spherical coords as:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4} r \cos(\theta )r^2\sin(\varphi ) \;dr\,d\theta \,d\varphi  $$

I try this on Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[r *Cos[theta]*r^2*Sin[phi], {r, 0, 4}], {theta, 0, Pi/2}], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

But re result is 0. What is wrong here?

Comment: What is $\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\,\sin(\phi)$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Version 9 currently, we can do ([using the Undocumented form of Integrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/undocumented-use-of-integrate-integrating-over-regions/48167#48167)):

```
Integrate[Boole[z >= 0] z, {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 4]]
```

> 64 Pi

**Note:** This is undocumented behaviour and functionality may change or behave differently in newer versions of *Mathematica* so use with caution e.g. as noted by Szabolcs in the comment, `Sphere` in V10 denotes a surface, whereas in V9 it represents a volume. So we should keep this in mind or we can get as fancy as V10 and use `BallRegion` (equivalent to `Ball` as Szabolcs did). To do this, first load the [Region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39184/any-ideas-on-how-to-use-the-region-context?lq=1) context

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[]
```

Then:

```
Integrate[ Boole[z >= 0] z, {x, y, z} ∈ BallRegion[{0, 0, 0}, 4]]
```

> 64 Pi

Comment: Ok, thanks, the funny thing is that if i do it by hand it gives me 0 too...

Comment: @Wyvern666 Just keep in mind the caveats about undocumented functionality.  In v9 it's a work-in-progress, so it may break, give wrong results, etc.

Comment: An important note: in version 10 `Sphere` denotes a *surface*, not a volume region.  So in v10 `Integrate[Boole[z >= 0] z, {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 4]]` is going to do a surface integral, which *accidentally* happens to have the same result the volume integral would for a radius of 4 (but not for other values).  There might be a lot of confusion because of this accident ... you might want to mention this difference.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thanks, note added.

Comment: @Wyvern666 that's because you mixed up the polar and azimuthal angles, so the integral you gave really does vanish (as I attempted to hint in my comment to your question). See Jens's answer for the correct form.

Answer (score 12):

Since you explicitly asked for a way to do this integral in spherical coordinates, here is a formulation that works in all versions of *Mathematica*. First I define the spherical coordinates, and then I do the triple integral using the Jacobi determinant:

```
{x, y, z} = 
  r {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]};

Integrate[
 z Abs[Det[D[{x, y, z}, {{r, θ, ϕ}}]]], 
   {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* ==> 64 Pi *)
```

Answer (score 7):

The more natural way to express this problem is

```
Integrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 16] z, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 4}]

(* ==> 64 Pi *)
```

This works in version 9 and earlier.  In version 10 we can get fancy and do

```
Integrate[Boole[z >= 0] z, {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 4]]

(* ==> 64 Pi *)
```

Comment: Is version 10 of Mathematica available already?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z The [programming cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/) is available.  It's possible to try these with a free account.

Answer (score 7):

You set up the integral incorrectly. You are mixing up $\varphi$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your mathematica code. The problem is with the volume element.
The volume element in spherical coordinates is 
$$r^2\sin(\theta ) \;dr\,d\theta \,d\varphi  $$ not
$$r^2\sin(\varphi ) \;dr\,d\theta \,d\varphi  $$
Simply replace $$Sin[phi]$$ with $$Sin[theta]$$ in your code, and you get the answer.

```
Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[r *Cos[theta]*r^2*Sin[theta], {r, 0, 4}], {theta, 0, Pi/2}], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using Cartesian coordinate:

```
4 Integrate[
  Integrate[
   Integrate[z, {x, 0, Sqrt[16 - y^2 - z^2]}], {y, 0, 
    Sqrt[16 - z^2]}], {z, 0, 4}]

(* 64 Pi *)
```