# Integral over geometric region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I'd like to calculate this integral

$$
\int_E y\ dydz
$$ 
where $E = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 : z^2+6 < y^2 < 5z \}$

By hand i've got $\frac{1}{12}$ but i'm not sure, and i'd like to verify this integral and others.

I tried using ParametricRegion

```
ParametricRegion[{{y, z}, 6 + z^2 < y^2 < 5 z}]
Integrate[y, {z, y} \[Element] Region]
```

The result is very strange

```
(52 Sqrt[2/5])/3 - 14 Sqrt[3/5]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to plot and find the volume of a solid?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/how-to-plot-and-find-the-volume-of-a-solid),  also [Undocumented use of Integrate: Integrating over regions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/undocumented-use-of-integrate-integrating-over-regions)

Comment: Artes, have you seen the specific geometric region? I don't know integration extremes!

Comment: Your hand result is correct for y>0 .  Note you have a mirrored region ( y<0 ) which cancels so the result should be zero.

Comment: @george2079 thank you. It's right to consider just the right (or the left) side because i've to study a rotation solid and this is the plane shape that i've to rotate! thank you! Have you solved it by hand or with mathematica?

Comment: uh.. you've reversed {y,z} in the region and integral.. (and I cut paste the error ) Fix that and it works  (add y>0 to the region to get 1/12 )

Comment: @george2079 thank you!

Comment: @george2079 i tried with another function and domain: this is the input and the output http://i60.tinypic.com/eb8s5u.png  Did i wrong something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote it it obviously vanishes, since all the conditions are on $y^2$ while the integrand is $y$ (so whatever the $y>0$ bit contributes is cancelled by the $y<0$ bit).

If you meant for $y>0$ to be true, then eg

```
Integrate[y*Boole[z^2 + 6 < y^2] 
    Boole[y^2 < 5 z] Boole[0 < y], {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

give $1/12$.

But this sort of thing breaks down the moment you increase complexity.