# ParametricRegion question - a bug report

Tags: version-10, usage-messages

It is just to report that the request:

```
?ParametricRegion
```

does not return the expected definition. Instead I see this:

```
 System`ParametricRegion

Attributes[ParametricRegion]={HoldAll,Protected}
```

it is Mma10.0.0 (PC, Win7)

Comment: I presume you are complaining that there is no `::usage` message associated with this Symbol?

Comment: Can replicate. I think it's a bug.

Comment: I don't believe a missing usage message constitutes a bug, so I removed that tag.  If anyone disagrees I will happily listen to your argument.

Comment: Oh I thought it was some MMA 10 thing i.e. previous MMA versions did show the usage blurb. If that's not true then I don't know why WRI would omit it from that function :/

Comment: @seismatica You should still have usage messages for other functions.  This is a new-in-10 function and they apparently forgot the usage message.  There are lots of small (and some not so small) errors in the current documentation and this appears to be one of them.

Comment: It also does not have the "New in 10" designation in the documentation.

Comment: @RunnyKine It does say on bottom of the page (at least on the web): "Introduced in 10 (10.0)". It's part of geometric computation functionality. I think there was some undocumented functionality like this in version 9, but nothing official.

Comment: @kirma. I know it's new. I actually used it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/undocumented-use-of-integrate-integrating-over-regions/48167#48167) as an undocumented function in V9. I'm just stating it was omitted,

Comment: @RunnyKine Ah, I got it the other way round. :)