# Is there a way to increase the smoothness of a cylinder?

Tags: graphics3d, rendering

I am using `Cylinder` to produce wide flat disks (in *Mathematica* 8). This works just fine except that the circular base of such a cylinder turns out to be really just a 40-gon which is simply too coarse an approximation to a circle  for what I have in mind. Is there a way to convince *Mathematica* to use say a 200-gon as a circular base for a cylinder?

Here is an example of the kind of picture that I am trying to create. Zoom in to see how coarse the cylinders' curved surfaces pan out.

```
Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, 0.`, -0.9510565162951536`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, 0.`, 0.9510565162951536`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.85065080835204`, 0.`, -0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.85065080835204`, 0.`, 0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.6881909602355868`, -0.5`, -0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.6881909602355868`, 0.5`, -0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.6881909602355868`, -0.5`, 0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.6881909602355868`, 0.5`, 0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.2628655560595668`, -0.8090169943749475`, \
-0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.2628655560595668`, 
      0.8090169943749475`, -0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.2628655560595668`, -0.8090169943749475`, 
      0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.2628655560595668`, 0.8090169943749475`, 
      0.42532540417601994`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, 0.`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, 0.`, 1.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.42532540417602`, 0.3090169943749474`, 
      0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.7236067977499789`, 0.5257311121191336`, 
      0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.16245984811645317`, 0.5`, 0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.2628655560595668`, 0.8090169943749473`, 
      0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.27639320225002106`, 0.8506508083520399`, 
      0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.42532540417602`, -0.3090169943749474`, 
      0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.7236067977499789`, -0.5257311121191336`, 
      0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.85065080835204`, 0.`, 0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.16245984811645317`, -0.5`, 0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.27639320225002106`, -0.8506508083520399`, 
      0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.2628655560595668`, -0.8090169943749473`, 
      0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.5257311121191336`, 0.`, 0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.8944271909999159`, 0.`, 0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.6881909602355868`, -0.5`, 0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.6881909602355868`, 0.5`, 0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.7236067977499789`, -0.5257311121191336`, \
-0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.42532540417602`, -0.3090169943749474`, \
-0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, 0.`, -1.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.2628655560595668`, -0.8090169943749473`, \
-0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.16245984811645317`, -0.5`, -0.8506508083520399`}}, .1],
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.27639320225002106`, -0.8506508083520399`, \
-0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.7236067977499789`, 
      0.5257311121191336`, -0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.42532540417602`, 
      0.3090169943749474`, -0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.85065080835204`, 0.`, -0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.27639320225002106`, 
      0.8506508083520399`, -0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.16245984811645317`, 0.5`, -0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.2628655560595668`, 
      0.8090169943749473`, -0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.8944271909999159`, 0.`, -0.4472135954999579`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.5257311121191336`, 0.`, -0.8506508083520399`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.6881909602355868`, 0.5`, -0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.6881909602355868`, -0.5`, -0.5257311121191336`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, 1.`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.5877852522924731`, 0.8090169943749473`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.9510565162951535`, 0.3090169943749474`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.9510565162951535`, -0.3090169943749474`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {-0.5877852522924731`, -0.8090169943749473`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 0.0011 {0.`, -1.`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.5877852522924731`, -0.8090169943749473`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.9510565162951535`, -0.3090169943749474`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.9510565162951535`, 0.3090169943749474`, 0.`}}, .1], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, 
    0.0011 {0.5877852522924731`, 0.8090169943749473`, 0.`}}, .1]}]
```

Comment: I think I've seen someone use a hidden option once for sphere's but I cannot find where ...

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you determine it is a 40-gon?

Comment: I am experimenting with exporting Mathematica output in .stl format for 3d printing. This sort of exporting seems to work well if it only involves basic objects like cylinders but seems to prone to create problems when you try to export fancier stuff. Anyway, here is what a collection of cylinders looks like when you preview it at [Shapeways](http://www.qedcat.com/images/shape1.jpg). To determine that it's a 40-gon just output to pdf and then have a close look in a vector graphics program.

Comment: I pulled the `version-8` tag since this applies multiple versions.

Comment: Be a bit careful with this, the printing engine may get confused by intersecting surfaces, as nothing physical can have these. It may leave the interior area open and your design would not work. Offcourse any mathematical preview would have no problem with intersection and it would be hard to see intersections. Altough shapeways is probably aware of this, but if you were to do this on your own then...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can fix this problem by using the following Option in `Graphics3D`:

```
Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> {200, 1}}
```

Adjust `200` to match your requirements.  (Indeed the default is `40`.)

*Edit:* I don't know exactly what the second parameter does, but using the single parameter form shown in the documentation linked below results in a big slow-down.  I could guess that it is points in the other direction but that doesn't seem to make sense.  Anyway I can't tell the visual difference between `{200, 1}` and `{200, 200}` but the former is much faster than the latter.  (`"CylinderPoints" -> 200` is apparently equivalent to `"CylinderPoints" -> {200, 200}`.)

You can make the change permanent with the Option Inspector by changing this value in the `Graphics3DBoxOptions`:

[image]

From [Three-Dimensional Graphics Primitives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ThreeDimensionalGraphicsPrimitives.html):

> Even though `Cone`, `Cylinder`, `Sphere`, and `Tube` produce high-quality renderings, their usage is scalable. A single image can contain thousands of these primitives. When rendering so many primitives, you can increase the efficiency of rendering by using special options to change the number of points used by default to render `Cone`, `Cylinder`, `Sphere`, and `Tube`. The `"ConePoints"` `Method` option to `Graphics3D` is used to reduce the rendering quality of each individual cone. Cylinder, sphere, and tube quality can be similarly adjusted using `"CylinderPoints"`, `"SpherePoints"`, and `"TubePoints"`, respectively.

40 points:

[image]

200 points:

[image]

Comment: Crushed it as usual. What does the second element in the option setting do? I don't see an explanation in the docs.

Comment: @mfvonh It is apparently superfluous based on the example in the tutorial I just linked.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I hope it was not presumptuous of me to add pictures to show your solution in all its glory :)

Comment: @mfvonh Thanks for the examples!

Comment: Here is a follow-up question. Although everything looks fine on-screen Mathematica does something unexpected when you try  then export the model to .stl format (Export["looksgood.stl",%]). The first suspicious thing is that the export virtually takes no time. Why this is so becomes apparent when one opens such an .stl file in a previewer. All of a sudden all the cylinders are  represented as [20-gons](http://www.qedcat.com/images/shape2.jpg) regardless of how smooth they are represented on screen.

Comment: @BurkardPolster That's unfortunate.  Possibly there is a separate place this Option can be added to affect export.  I haven't found it yet however.

Comment: @BurkardPolster I added a different approach to my answer that creates the cylinders in such a way as to preserve them during `Export`.

Comment: I would assume that the second parameter is for the number of points on the other axis; there's no reason to subdivide your cylinder lengthwise, but by default it probably sets the lengthwise divisions to the same as the first parameter.

Answer (score 9):

The direct answer has been given by Mr. Wizard already, but there is also another way that renders smoothly while giving some additional advantages:

Use `Tube` instead of `Cylinder`. One advantage is that `Tube` allows you to do additional styling with `VertexColors`, not supported by `Cylinder`.

I will assume that we named your large list of `Cylinder` objects `artwork`. Using this, you can render the `Tube` version like this:

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Butt"], 
 artwork /. Cylinder -> Tube}, 
 Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 600}]
```

[image: Tube]

Here, `TubePoints` is the equivalent to `CylinderPoints` in Mr.Wizard's answer. I deliberately cranked up the number of points to `600` to see if there is any noticeable lag with `Tube`. It seems that this method produces output that is just as responsive as the `Cylinder` method with `Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> {600, 1}}`.

**Edit to address follow-up question about Export**

As was not initially clear, the ultimate goal of the question is to produce a 3D graphics that can be exported to `STL` format at the same vertex count that is displayed in *Mathematica*.

This is **not the case** with solutions based on `Cylinder` or `Tube` as far as we've been able to tell so far. Therefore, I revisited [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29739/245) where I made a custom cylinder function motivated by the desire to incorporate `VertexNormals`. It's slight overkill here because that function allows an arbitrary cross-sectional shape which we don't need here. But since I already have it, this seemed easiest to me. Also, `prism` can be used in its own right to generalize the question.

First I recall the function `prism` from that answer, and then I wrap it by a function `cyl` that emulates a `Cylinder` between two points:

```
ClearAll[prism]
prism[pts_List, h_] := 
 Module[{bottoms, tops, surfacePoints, sidePoints},
  surfacePoints = 
   Table[Map[PadRight[#, 3, height] &, pts], {height, {0, h}}];
  {bottoms, tops} = {Most[#], Rest[#]} &@surfacePoints;
  sidePoints = 
   Flatten[{bottoms, RotateLeft[bottoms, {0, 1}], 
     RotateLeft[tops, {0, 1}], tops}, {{2, 3}, {1}}];
  MapThread[
   Polygon[#1, VertexNormals -> (#1 - #2)] &,
   {
    Join[sidePoints, surfacePoints],
    Join[Map[{0, 0, 1} # &, sidePoints, {2}],
     Map[({1, 1, 0} # + {0, 0, h/2}) &, surfacePoints, {2}]
     ]
    }
   ]
  ]

cyl[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_, n_: 90] := Module[{
   circle = 
    r Table[{Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, Pi/n, 2 Pi, Pi/n}],
   h = EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]},
  GeometricTransformation[prism[circle, h], 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[pt1], 
    Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1.}, pt2 - pt1}], 
      Identity]]]]]

gg = Graphics3D[artwork /. Cylinder -> cyl];

Export["gg.stl", gg]
```

The result is in `gg`, and the default vertex count around the perimeter is `n=90`. You can verify in an external program that this count is preserved in the `Export`. Here is what it looks like in Blender with the default `90` polygon points:

[image: blender]

Comment: Oops, looks like the second parameter was important after all!  It's super slow without it.  I'll be curious to know how this compares to `Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> {200, 1}}` on your machine.

Comment: That does the trick! With `Method -> {"CylinderPoints" -> {600, 1}}` your plot seems to be just as responsive as the `Tube` version. So the speed isn't an issue anymore, and I'll edit my answer to account for your update.

Comment: Good; I'm seeing the same behavior here.  +1 for showing a different way.

Comment: Looks like a great solution with a lot of scope for refining the output, e.g. by using a ring as a cross-section instead of a circle to create an empty core. Thank you very much for your help with solving this problem, and thank you also again to Mr. Wizard.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a replacement for `Cylinder` that uses splines.

```
Clear[splineCylinder];
splineCylinder[{a_, b_}, r_: 1] :=
  Module[{
    base = r {{0, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0},
              {-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}},
    weights = {1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1},
    knots = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1},
    transform, baseA, baseB
    },
    transform = If[Chop@Cross[{0, 0, 1}, b - a] == {0, 0, 0}, Identity, 
      RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, Normalize[b - a]}]];
    baseA = a + transform@# & /@ base;
    baseB = b + transform@# & /@ base;

    BSplineSurface[#, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {Automatic, knots}, 
      SplineWeights -> {weights, weights}, SplineClosed -> {False, True}] & /@
    {
      {baseA, baseB},
      {baseA, a + 0 # & /@ base},
      {baseB, b + 0 # & /@ base}
    }
  ]
```

It's smoother, yet slower.  It also has a balloon knot in the centre of each cap.  But you can't see that in your graphic.

[image: splineCylinder]

Edit: This fails utterly to be exported to an STL file.  It appears that exporting a 3D spline is not yet fully implemented in Mathematica (9.0.1).

Comment: I was waiting for someone to post this. +1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could hack together disks using a plotting function (and use `PlotPoints` if necessary)?

```
PolarPlot[1, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 1000];
Cases[%, _Line, Infinity] /. {p__?NumberQ} :> {p, 0};
%[[1,1]] // Length
%% // Graphics3D
```

> 1761

[image]

Comment: I am experimenting with exporting Mathematica output in .stl format for 3d printing. This sort of exporting seems to work well if it only involves basic objects like cylinders but seems to prone to create problems when you try to export fancier stuff. Anyway, here is what a collection of cylinders looks like when you preview it at [Shapeways](http://www.qedcat.com/images/shape1.jpg).